# Python array sum vs MATLAB

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, matlab, numpy

I'm slowly switching to Python and I wanted to make a simple test for comparing the performance of a simple array summation. I generate a random 1000x1000 array and add one to each of the values in this array.

Here my script in Python :

```
import time

import numpy
from numpy.random import random

def testAddOne(data):
    """
    Test addOne
    """
    return data + 1

i = 1000
data = random((i,i))
start = time.clock()
for x in xrange(1000): 
    testAddOne(data)

stop = time.clock()
print stop - start
```

And my function in MATLAB:

```
function test
%parameter declaration
c=rand(1000);

tic
for t = 1:1000
    testAddOne(c);
end
fprintf('Structure: \n')
toc
end

function testAddOne(c)
c = c + 1;
end
```

The Python takes 2.77 - 2.79 seconds, the same as the MATLAB function (I'm actually quite impressed by Numpy!). What would I have to change to my Python script to use multithreading? I can't in MATLAB since I don,t have the toolbox.

Comment: Is that really fair on `MATLAB`, to add one element at a time, when you can do in one go and because that's where the power of MATLAB lies in? If you `inline` the function, I won't be surprised if you get some appreciable improvement with `MATLAB`.

Comment: @Divakar You should check the code again, MATLAB is adding the ones in a single call. What is probably misleading you is that I'm running this 1000 times, which also correspond to the length of the array. To understand, the for loop `t = 1:1000` could be `t = 1:randi([1000,2000])`

Comment: My point is that MATLAB is not good when you do operations on one element at a time. That's why for example if you do matrix multiplication one element at a time and compare with the built-in matrix multiplication, you would see the huge difference in performance.

Comment: That's right, hence why my function is using the MATLAB vectorized approach. If I didn't do this, I would have to use two for loop statement i and j and going through each index to add one. Which like you said, wouldn't use the power of MATLAB.

Comment: Looks like a fair comparison.

Comment: Some relevant discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11442191/553404), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5260068/553404) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16617973/553404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi *threading* in Python is only useful for situations where threads get blocked, e.g. on getting input, which is not the case here (see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies) for more details). However, multi *processing* is easy to do in Python. Multiprocessing in general is covered [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

A program taking a similar approach to your example is below

```
import time
import numpy
from numpy.random import random
from multiprocessing import Process

def testAddOne(data):
    return data + 1

def testAddN(data,N):
    # print "testAddN", N
    for x in xrange(N): 
        testAddOne(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    matrix_size = 1000
    num_adds = 10000
    num_processes = 4

    data = random((matrix_size,matrix_size))

    start = time.clock()
    if num_processes > 1:
        processes = [Process(target=testAddN, args=(data,num_adds/num_processes))
                     for i in range(num_processes)]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
    else:
        testAddN(data,num_adds)

    stop = time.clock()
    print "Elapsed", stop - start
```

A more useful example using a [pool of worker processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) to successively add 1 to different matrices is below.

```
import time
import numpy
from numpy.random import random
from multiprocessing import Pool

def testAddOne(data):
    return data + 1

def testAddN(dataN):
    data,N=dataN
    for x in xrange(N): 
        data = testAddOne(data)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_matrices = 4
    matrix_size = 1000
    num_adds_per_matrix = 2500

    num_processes = 4

    inputs = [(random((matrix_size,matrix_size)), num_adds_per_matrix)
              for i in range(num_matrices)]
    #print inputs # test using, e.g., matrix_size = 2

    start = time.clock()

    if num_processes > 1:
        proc_pool = Pool(processes=num_processes)
        outputs = proc_pool.map(testAddN, inputs)    
    else:
        outputs = map(testAddN, inputs)

    stop = time.clock()
    #print outputs # test using, e.g., matrix_size = 2
    print "Elapsed", stop - start
```

In this case the code in `testAddN` actually does something with the result of calling `testAddOne`. And you can uncomment the print statements to check that some useful work is being done.

In both cases I've changed the total number of additions to 10000; with fewer additions the cost of starting up processes becomes more significant (but you can experiment with the parameters). And you can experiment with `num_processes` also. On my machine I found that compared to running in the same process with `num_processes=1` I got just under a 2x speedup spawning four processes with `num_processes=4`.

Comment: I'm trying your first example right now, and I got a 2.16x speedup (with 4 processes)

Comment: Still trying to understand what you are doing in the second example! But thanks for both solutions!

Comment: @m_power thanks for the feedback! In computing `map` is used to mean take one list `L`, process each element in the list with some function `f`, producing another list `L'`. The list `L=[x0, x1, ..., xn]` becomes `L=[f(x0), f(x1), ..., f(xn)]`. What I really like about the Python process pool is that a multi-process map looks almost exactly the same as the single-process map.