# multithreading running slower than single thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to profile a basic function in Python to see the comparative advantage of multithreading for evaluating its results.  It seems the threaded version performs increasingly worse as the size of the data across which the function is applied increases.  Is there overhead in starting threads that I'm not taking into account here?  Can someone explain how to actually achieve multithreaded optimization / what I'm doing wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

pool = Pool(processes=4)

import timeit
print timeit.timeit('map(f, range(20000000))', setup = "from __main__ import f", number = 1)
print timeit.timeit('pool.map(f, range(20000000))', setup = "from __main__ import f, pool", number = 1)
```

Results:

```
5.90005707741
11.8840620518
[Finished in 18.9s]
```

If relevant, I ran this in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: You talk about multithreading but you don't use threads at all.  I'm not saying multiprocessing is bad (it's usually good!), but your terminology is confusing.

Comment: Do you have a CPU that is capable of processing? If not then there is a sort of simulated multithreading that happens. Not sure if thats what's causing this but I think its possible

Comment: you know that multi-processing is not the same as multi-threading. I would imagine that the reason this performs worse (in this case) is that your process doesn't do much, but there is a lot of overhead in setting up the processes, communicating with them etc.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using threads instead of processes but I still want a "mapping" function / want to be able to retrieve return values from the threads.  When I was searching for a way to do that I was directed to the multiprocessing module.

Comment: I would think that if you used multi-threading, the performance might be even worse - as your multi-threaded function is far too small.

Comment: This job is more in the range of OpenMP than multiprocessing. You're just spending lots of time on transferring data between processes and a negligible amount on processing. In Python, you'd leave it to numpy, and per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442191/parallelizing-a-numpy-vector-operation numexpr would handle this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "unit of work" you do in each job is way too small.  This is often a concern when you "map" jobs like this--the overhead of the mapping process dominates.  Of course mapping a job to a separate process is more time consuming than mapping in the same process, so it is no surprise that the multiprocess solution is slower.

Try it with a function that does a lot more computation and you will see the benefits of multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

@john has already given the answer but I want to provide an example too

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(n):#fibonacci
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return f(n-1) + f(n-2)

pool = Pool(processes=4)

import timeit

print timeit.timeit('map(f, xrange(35))', setup = "from __main__ import f", number = 1)
print timeit.timeit('pool.map(f, xrange(35))', setup = "from __main__ import f, pool", number = 1)
```

Result:

```
4.349
2.497
```