# Parallelize operations for each cell in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, theano

I am trying to figure out which is the best way to parallelize the execution of a single operation for each cell in a 2D numpy array.

In particular, I need to do a bitwise operation for each cell in the array.

This is what I do using a single `for` cycle:

```
for x in range(M):
    for y in range(N):
        v[x][y] = (v[x][y] >> 7) & 255
```

I found a way to do the same above using the `vectorize` method:

```
def f(x):
    return (x >> 7) & 255
f = numpy.vectorize(f)

v = f(v)
```

However, using vectorize doesn't seem to improve performance.

I read about *numexpr* in [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460119/738017), where also *Theano* and *Cython* are cited. *Theano* in particular seems a good solution, but I cannot find examples that fit my case.

So my question is: which is the best way to improve the above code, using parallelization and possibly GPU computation? May someone post some sample code to do this?

Comment: You could look at `multiprocessing.Pool`, by defining a function for your bitwise operation and sending the list of all your cells. It will then use all your processors to evaluate the result, but you wiil need to reconstruct the array, wich can make you lose time. How big is your array? how long does your calculation take?

Comment: With such a simple element-wise transform, the overall performance may be memory IO bound.  I.e., moving data to/from a GPU may make the operation slower overall.

Comment: Correct the indentation and variable names in the 1st code piece.

Comment: @hpaulj, I've just done, thanks

Comment: The normal way to index an 2d array is `v[x,y]`.  Using `[x][y]` may be equivalent here, but if `v[x]` produces a copy rather than a view, it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with bitwise operations but this here gives me the same result as your code and is vectorized.

```
import numpy as np

# make sure it is a numpy.array
v = np.array(v)

# vectorized computation
N = (v >> 7) & 255
```