# Crunching history data for a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails application which is mainly used to show data to the users through dashboards.

- The application is currently running on a PostgreSQL database.
- All the history values stored so far are in the form [date,variable,value].
- The records can be stored every 5 minutes, and the number of variables I'm tracking is high, aka, millions of records in the history table.

Now I need to do operations in between variables. So let's say I have a variable A and a variable B, I would need:

- the value of A/B.
- the history of A/B calculated every t (which can be 5 minutes/1 day/1 week).

Currently I am doing everything within the Rails environment, but I know that Ruby isn't a fast language so I'm planning a change.

In the near future I would also need to calculate derivatives and integrals so I was thinking that I might need a dedicated/decoupled services that only does data crunching.

What would be a good tool/language that allows me to do complex math operations on large set of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be a good tool/language that allows me to do complex math operations on large set of data?

Python and numpy/[scipy](https://www.scipy.org) are what you need! I'm not trying to sell some python to a ruby afficionado, but I can vouch for these packages, they're awesome.

It's close to matlab where you manipulate native vector/matrix data types, using functions that support vectorization. It can use openmp for parallelism, there is also [numexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460119/144450). It is both very fast and very easy to use, plus the library is enormous, here is an [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to peufeu answer, I could find these guys: http://sciruby.com/