# Why built-in functions like abs works on numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I feel surprised that `abs` works on numpy array but not on lists. Why is that?

```
import numpy as np

abs(np.array((1,-2)))
array([1, 2])

abs([1,-1])
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
```

Also, built in functions like `sum` also works on numpy array. I guess it is because numpy array supports `__getitem__`? But in case of `abs`, if it depends on `__getitem__` it should work for list as well, but it didn't.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's because `numpy.ndarray` implements the `__abs__(self)` method. Just provide it for your own class, and `abs()` will magically work. For non-builtin types you can also provide this facility after-the-fact. E.g.

```
class A:
    "A class without __abs__ defined"
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

def A_abs(a):
    "An 'extension' method that will be added to `A`"
    return abs(a.v)

# Make abs() work with an instance of A
A.__abs__ = A_abs
```

However, this will not work for built-in types, such as `list` or `dict`.

Answer (score 5):

`abs` function looks for `__abs__` method.

you can also, like numpy, implement the `__abs__` method in your classes so abs would works with them.

i.e.

```
class A(object):
    def __abs__(self):
        return 8

>>> a= A()
>>> abs(a)
8
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`sum` works on iterables, such as list or numpy arrays.

`abs` works on values which define an `__abs__` method, such as numbers or numpy.arrays:

```
>>> x = -1
>>> x.__abs__()
1

>>> class A(object):
...     def __abs__(self):
...         return 12
>>> a = A()
>>> abs(a)
12
```

`list`s do not define this method, although you can use map or list comprehensions (`map(abs, [1, -1])` and `[abs(x) for x in [1,-1]]` respectively) for what you required. If you like overkill, you can also subclass list and define a numpy-like `__abs__` (but the comprehension is generally preferable)