# How to check if two arrays are equal but opposite in sign?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried using

```
np.array_equal(A,B)
```

but of course this doesn't acknowledge the different signs the two will have.

My arrays have the same number but they are either positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if two arrays are equal element-wise *disregarding the sign* of each element, use their absolute values<sup>1</sup>:

```
np.array_equal(abs(A), abs(B))

# [-1, 2, 3], [1,  2, -3] → True
# [-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, -3] → True
```

If you want to check if two arrays are equal while *every pair of elements has exact opposite signs* (a stricter comparison than the first case), use the negation of one array:

```
np.array_equal(A, -B)

# [-1, 2, 3], [1,  2, -3] → False
# [-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, -3] → True
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The built-in `abs` function will call `np.abs` [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953127/why-built-in-functions-like-abs-works-on-numpy-array).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`absolute()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html#numpy.absolute) function in the numpy library as:

```
np.array_equal(np.abs(A), np.abs(B))
```