# What is the difference between math.exp and numpy.exp and why do numpy creators choose to introduce exp again?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`exp` means exponential function. Why do `numpy` creators introduce this function again?

- [`math.exp`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html)
- [`numpy.exp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html)

Comment: The numpy one accepts an array, the math version will work on a scalar object type only. The numpy one will perform `exp` on the entire array, it is a vectorised method of performing the function on the entire array this is what it's designed for

Comment: `numpy.exp()` may be called on array and there is a good chance computation will be paralleled (like a lot of vector / matrix operations in numpy). This gain is a main reason to this kind of libraries in first place.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `math.exp` works only for scalars, whereas `numpy.exp` will work for arrays.

Example:

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.]
>>> math.exp(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    math.exp(x)
TypeError: a float is required
>>> np.exp(x)
array([   2.71828183,    7.3890561 ,   20.08553692,   54.59815003,
        148.4131591 ])
```

It is the same case for other `math` functions.

```
>>> math.sin(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    math.sin(x)
TypeError: a float is required
>>> np.sin(x)
array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427])
```

Also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650194/are-numpys-math-functions-faster-than-pythons) to check out how `numpy` is faster than `math`.

Answer (score 8):

`math.exp` works on a single number, the numpy version works on numpy arrays and is tremendously faster due to the benefits of vectorization. The `exp` function isn't alone in this - several `math` functions have numpy counterparts, such as `sin`, `pow`, etc.

Consider the following:

```
In [10]: import math

In [11]: import numpy

In [13]: arr = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 500, 100000)

In [14]: %timeit numpy.exp(arr)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit [math.exp(i) for i in arr]
100 loops, best of 3: 17.9 ms per loop
```

The numpy version is ~9x faster (and probably can be made faster still by a careful choice of optimized math libraries)

As @camz states below - the `math` version will be faster when working on single values (in a quick test, ~7.5x faster).

Comment: Might be worth noting that the math version will be faster than the numpy one when only used on a single value and not a whole array.

Answer (score -1):

If you manually vectorize math.exp using map, it is faster than numpy. As far as I tested..

%timeit np.exp(arr)

500 µs ± 3.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit map(math.exp, arr)

148 ns ± 4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

​

Comment: Just for anyone finding this later, I'm pretty sure the only reason this is so is because `map` doesn't actually evaluate anything. It returns an iterator. Try `%timeit list(map(math.exp, arr))` to force the map to evaluate, and you'll get `104 µs ± 9.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`