# Mixing Numpy and Python math -- why are there different implementations if they're each "wrappers"?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, floating-point

What motivates several implementations of the "same" underlying data primitives for float's, int's, double's, bool's, ... amongst TensorFlow, Numpy, PyTorch, JAX, ..., *and* Python itself? Furthermore, if `tf.float64` is purely a wrapper around the Numpy equivalent, why do we have *another* wrapper under `tf.experimental.numpy.float64` that's presumably going to be added in one of the next set of releases?

I can't very quickly produce an example, but I can recall from my deep learning course that friends and I would basically take turns having our nights ruined by issues with mixing them... random overflows and inaccuracies here and there that were eventually (at least seemingly) mended by swapping out `np.float64` for `tf.float64`.

Should I expect more performance out of one over another? Are these to save from wasteful allocations, etc, for e.g. something like having Python's `float` in an `np.ndarray` and so on?

Comment: At least with `numpy` you (almost) never need to create a np.float64` object diectly.  You may get one by indexing a `numpy` array.  But even then you don't need to worry about it being different from a python float.  I haven't installed `tensorflow` (too small a computer).

Comment: What you call 'implementations' are classes.  A class not only has (a) data values, but also methods, many of which are inherited.  `np.float64` inherits from a variety of more generic `numpy` classes, but also from base Python `float` (but `np.float32` does not).  A `ndarray` does not "contain" floats (at least not in the sense of python lists).  It has a databuffer - some sort of `c` array, that it can access byte by byte or in larger blocks like 8 byte doubles.  Also a `np.float64` object has many (but not all) of the methods of a `ndarray`, while `float` has none.

Comment: So the point to the wrappers would be, purely, compatibility? I suppose my confusion lies somewhere in the neighborhood of "it seems reasonable to require that someone using pytorch/ tensorflow/ ... work with numpy; generate some error otherwise"; between my recollection of those errors -- which, all things considered, might just not be complete just given that it's been a minute -- and lack of understanding of python package management, this seems wasteful, so there must be some extra motivation. e.g. TF's experimental numpy wrapping? new API? or new functionality?

Comment: Presumably to understand `tf.experimental.numpy.float64`, one has to first understand the `experimental.numpy` API, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/numpy.  I don't know how tensorflow is organized.  The closest I get to `tf` is helping people understand why their "ragged arrays" can't be turned into `tensors`.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between math.exp and numpy.exp and why do numpy creators choose to introduce exp again?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30712402/4518341), [What is the difference between import numpy and import math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41648058/4518341)