# Finding index of an item closest to the value in a list that's not entirely sorted

Tags: python, list, search

As an example my list is:

```
[25.75443, 26.7803, 25.79099, 24.17642, 24.3526, 22.79056, 20.84866,
 19.49222, 18.38086, 18.0358, 16.57819, 15.71255, 14.79059, 13.64154,
 13.09409, 12.18347, 11.33447, 10.32184, 9.544922, 8.813385, 8.181152,
 6.983734, 6.048035, 5.505096, 4.65799]
```

and I'm looking for the index of the value closest to `11.5`. I've tried other methods such as binary search and `bisect_left` but they don't work.

I cannot sort this array, because the index of the value will be used on a similar array to fetch the value at that index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [from list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett How can this question be a duplicate of the other question. This question is older.

Comment: @QiuYU Because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value#comment81513949_12141150)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Try the following:

```
min(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: abs(a[i]-11.5))
```

For example:

```
>>> a = [25.75443, 26.7803, 25.79099, 24.17642, 24.3526, 22.79056, 20.84866, 19.49222, 18.38086, 18.0358, 16.57819, 15.71255, 14.79059, 13.64154, 13.09409, 12.18347, 11.33447, 10.32184, 9.544922, 8.813385, 8.181152, 6.983734, 6.048035, 5.505096, 4.65799]
>>> min(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: abs(a[i]-11.5))
16
```

Or to get the index and the value:

```
>>> min(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-11.5))
(16, 11.33447)
```

Comment: `def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array);
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin();
    return idx;`
performs much faster (inspired in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566508/1273751)

Answer (score 18):

```
import numpy as np

a = [25.75443, 26.7803, 25.79099, 24.17642, 24.3526, 22.79056, 20.84866, 19.49222, 18.38086, 18.0358, 16.57819, 15.71255, 14.79059, 13.64154, 13.09409, 12.18347, 11.33447, 10.32184, 9.544922, 8.813385, 8.181152, 6.983734, 6.048035, 5.505096, 4.65799]

index = np.argmin(np.abs(np.array(a)-11.5))
a[index] # here is your result
```

In case a is already an array, the corresponding transformation can be ommitted.

Answer (score 2):

How about: you zip the two lists, then sort the result?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't sort the array, then there is no quick way to find the closest item - you have to iterate over all entries.

There is a workaround but it's quite a bit of work: Write a sort algorithm which sorts the array and (at the same time) updates a second array which tells you where this entry was *before* the array was sorted.

That way, you can use binary search to look up index of the closest entry and then use this index to look up the original index using the "index array".

**[EDIT]** Using `zip()`, this is pretty simple to achieve:

```
 array_to_sort = zip( original_array, range(len(original_array)) )
 array_to_sort.sort( key=i:i[0] )
```

Now you can binary search for the value (using `item[0]`). `item[1]` will give you the original index.

Answer (score 2):

Going through all the items is only linear. If you would sort the array that would be worse.

I don't see a problem on keeping an additional `deltax` (the min difference so far) and `idx` (the index of that element) and just loop once trough the list.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if space isn't important you can sort any list without moving the contents by creating a secondary list of the sorted indices.

Also bear in mind that if you are doing this look up just once, then you will just have to traverse every element in the list O(n). (If multiple times then you probably would want to sort for increase efficiency later)

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching a long list a lot of times, then `min` scales very bad (O(n^2), if you append some of your searches to the search list, I think).

Bisect is your friend. Here's my solution. It scales O(n*log(n)):

```
class Closest:
    """Assumes *no* redundant entries - all inputs must be unique"""
    def __init__(self, numlist=None, firstdistance=0):
        if numlist == None:
            numlist=[]
        self.numindexes = dict((val, n) for n, val in enumerate(numlist))
        self.nums = sorted(self.numindexes)
        self.firstdistance = firstdistance

    def append(self, num):
        if num in self.numindexes:
            raise ValueError("Cannot append '%s' it is already used" % str(num))
        self.numindexes[num] = len(self.nums)
        bisect.insort(self.nums, num)

    def rank(self, target):
        rank = bisect.bisect(self.nums, target)
        if rank == 0:
            pass
        elif len(self.nums) == rank:
            rank -= 1
        else:
            dist1 = target - self.nums[rank - 1]
            dist2 = self.nums[rank] - target
            if dist1 < dist2:
                rank -= 1
        return rank

    def closest(self, target):
        try:
            return self.numindexes[self.nums[self.rank(target)]]
        except IndexError:
            return 0

    def distance(self, target):
        rank = self.rank(target)
        try:
            dist = abs(self.nums[rank] - target)
        except IndexError:
            dist = self.firstdistance
        return dist
```

Use it like this:

```
a = [25.75443, 26.7803, 25.79099, 24.17642, 24.3526, 22.79056, 20.84866,
     19.49222, 18.38086, 18.0358, 16.57819, 15.71255, 14.79059, 13.64154,
     13.09409, 12.18347, 1.33447, 10.32184, 9.544922, 8.813385, 8.181152,
     6.983734, 6.048035, 5.505096, 4.65799]
targets = [1.0, 100.0, 15.0, 15.6, 8.0]
cl = Closest(a)
for x in targets:
    rank = cl.rank(x)
    print("Closest to %5.1f : rank=%2i num=%8.5f index=%2i " % (x, rank,
        cl.nums[rank], cl.closest(x)))
```

Will output:

```
Closest to   1.0 : rank= 0 num= 1.33447 index=16
Closest to 100.0 : rank=25 num=26.78030 index= 1
Closest to  15.0 : rank=12 num=14.79059 index=12
Closest to  15.6 : rank=13 num=15.71255 index=11
Closest to   8.0 : rank= 5 num= 8.18115 index=20
```

And:

```
cl.append(99.9)
x = 100.0
rank = cl.rank(x)
print("Closest to %5.1f : rank=%2i num=%8.5f index=%2i " % (x, rank,
    cl.nums[rank], cl.closest(x)))
```

Output:

```
Closest to 100.0 : rank=25 num=99.90000 index=25
```

Comment: Or simply use `cl.closest(target)`, right? Thanks for the code!

Comment: [It's impossible to find the minimum of an unsorted list in O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12441414/olog-n-algorithm-for-finding-max-of-array). Since we cannot know which sub-lists of the list are sorted, bisecting does not help, we have to touch each element.