# Python - find integer closest to 0 in list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding index of an item closest to the value in a list that's not entirely sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort)

I've got a list of positive and negative numbers in Python (`[237, 72, -18, 237, 236, 237, 60, -158, -273, -78, 492, 243]`). I want to find the number which is closest to 0. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort Looks like the same question was asked and answered.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

How about this:

```
lst = [237, 72, -18, 237, 236, 237, 60, -158, -273, -78, 492, 243]
min((abs(x), x) for x in lst)[1]
```

A nice and much shorter answer:

```
min(lst, key=abs)
```

Comment: Will always return negative number, if a negative and positive number are the closest to 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
reduce(lambda x, y : x if abs(y) > abs(x) else y, your_sequence)
```