# python - get item number from list

Tags: python, list, numbers, int

I just asked the following question:

[Python - find integer closest to 0 in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923657/python-find-integer-closest-to-0-in-list)

The best answer was to use: `min(lst, key=abs)`.

That code returns the item from the list.

How do I get the item **number** from the list? (i.e. `2` instead of `-18`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [237, 72, -18, 237, 236, 237, 60, -158, -273, -78, 492, 243]
>>> lst.index(min(lst, key=abs))
2
```

Comment: Note that this has to go through the list twice.

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to augment your list with indices:

```
min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]))
```

It'll return the index *and* closest-to-zero value, use `[0]` if you only need the index.

On your example:

```
>>> example = [237, 72, -18, 237, 236, 237, 60, -158, -273, -78, 492, 243]
>>> min(enumerate(example), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]))
(2, -18)
>>> min(enumerate(example), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]))[0]
2
```

This is very efficient (worst-case O(n)); you can use `example.index(min(example, key=abs))` as well, but that has to go through the list twice in the worst case (O(2n)).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`lst.index(min(lst, key=abs))`

Answer (score 1):

One way is after finding the integer you want to find, you can use "index"...

```
result = min(lst, key=abs)
index = lst.index(result)
print(index) # prints 2
```