# From list of integers, get number closest to a given value

Tags: python, list, sorting, integer

Given a list of integers, I want to find which number is the closest to a number I give in input:

```
>>> myList = [4, 1, 88, 44, 3]
>>> myNumber = 5
>>> takeClosest(myList, myNumber)
...
4
```

Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: what about also returning the index that this happened in the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding index of an item closest to the value in a list that's not entirely sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort)

Comment: @sancho.s Nicely spotted. Though the answers to this question are way better than the ones on that other question. So I'm going to vote to close the other one as duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 511, accepted):

If we are not sure that the list is sorted, we could use the [built-in `min()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=min#min), to find the element which has the minimum distance from the specified number.

```
>>> min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber))
4
```

Note that it also works with dicts with int keys, like `{1: "a", 2: "b"}`. This method takes O(n) time.

---

If the list is already sorted, or you could pay the price of sorting the array once only, use the bisection method illustrated in [@Lauritz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141511/224671) which only takes O(log n) time (note however checking if a list is already sorted is O(n) and sorting is O(n log n).)

Comment: Speaking in complexity, this is `O(n)`, where a little hacking with `bisect` will give you a massive improvement to `O(log n)` (if your input array is sorted).

Comment: @mic_e: That's just [Lauritz's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12141511/224671).

Comment: what about also returning the index that this happened in the list?

Comment: @CharlieParker Create your own implementation of `min`, run it over a dictionary (`items()`) instead of a list, and return the key instead of the value in the end.

Comment: Or use `numpy.argmin` instead of `min` to get the index instead of the value.

Answer (score 205):

I'll rename the function `take_closest` to conform with PEP8 naming conventions.

If you mean quick-to-execute as opposed to quick-to-write, `min` should **not** be your weapon of choice, except in one very narrow use case. The `min` solution needs to examine every number in the list *and* do a calculation for each number. Using [`bisect.bisect_left`](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) instead is almost always faster.

The "almost" comes from the fact that `bisect_left` requires the list to be sorted to work. Hopefully, your use case is such that you can sort the list once and then leave it alone. Even if not, as long as you don't need to sort before every time you call `take_closest`, the `bisect` module will likely come out on top. If you're in doubt, try both and look at the real-world difference.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def take_closest(myList, myNumber):
    """
    Assumes myList is sorted. Returns closest value to myNumber.

    If two numbers are equally close, return the smallest number.
    """
    pos = bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    if pos == 0:
        return myList[0]
    if pos == len(myList):
        return myList[-1]
    before = myList[pos - 1]
    after = myList[pos]
    if after - myNumber < myNumber - before:
        return after
    else:
        return before
```

Bisect works by repeatedly halving a list and finding out which half `myNumber` has to be in by looking at the middle value. This means it has a running time of **O(log n)** as opposed to the **O(n)** running time of the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141207/566644). If we compare the two methods and supply both with a sorted `myList`, these are the results:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "
from closest import take_closest
from random import randint
a = range(-1000, 1000, 10)" "take_closest(a, randint(-1100, 1100))"

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.22 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "
from closest import with_min
from random import randint
a = range(-1000, 1000, 10)" "with_min(a, randint(-1100, 1100))"

10000 loops, best of 3: 43.9 usec per loop
```

So in this particular test, `bisect` is almost 20 times faster. For longer lists, the difference will be greater.

What if we level the playing field by removing the precondition that `myList` must be sorted? Let's say we sort a copy of the list *every time* `take_closest` is called, while leaving the `min` solution unaltered. Using the 200-item list in the above test, the `bisect` solution is still the fastest, though only by about 30%.

This is a strange result, considering that the sorting step is **O(n log(n))**! The only reason `min` is still losing is that the sorting is done in highly optimalized c code, while `min` has to plod along calling a lambda function for every item. As `myList` grows in size, the `min` solution will eventually be faster. Note that we had to stack everything in its favour for the `min` solution to win.

Comment: Sorting itself needs O(N log N), so it will be slower when N is becoming large. For instance, if you use `a=range(-1000,1000,2);random.shuffle(a)` you'll find that `takeClosest(sorted(a), b)` would become slower.

Comment: @KennyTM I'll grant you that, and I'll point it out in my answer. But as long `getClosest` may be called more than once for every sort, this will be faster, and for the sort-once use case, it's a no-brainer.

Comment: what about also returning the index that this happened in the list?

Comment: If `myList` is already an `np.array` then using `np.searchsorted` in place of `bisect` is faster.

Comment: What if I would like to return not closes value, but it's ID?

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow I think you made a typo in the end of your answer, as you say "As mylist grows in size, the *min* solution will eventually be faster". However from the rest of your answer I am deducing that  *min* should become slower and slower instead

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> takeClosest = lambda num,collection:min(collection,key=lambda x:abs(x-num))
>>> takeClosest(5,[4,1,88,44,3])
4
```

A [lambda](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) is a special way of writing an "anonymous" function (a function that doesn't have a name). You can assign it any name you want because a lambda is an expression.

The "long" way of writing the the above would be:

```
def takeClosest(num,collection):
   return min(collection,key=lambda x:abs(x-num))
```

Comment: Note however, that assigning lambda's to names is discouraged according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Answer (score 8):

```
def closest(list, Number):
    aux = []
    for valor in list:
        aux.append(abs(Number-valor))

    return aux.index(min(aux))
```

This code will give you the index of the closest number of Number in the list.

The solution given by KennyTM is the best overall, but in the cases you cannot use it (like brython), this function will do the work

Answer (score 6):

Iterate over the list and compare the current closest number with `abs(currentNumber - myNumber)`:

```
def takeClosest(myList, myNumber):
    closest = myList[0]
    for i in range(1, len(myList)):
        if abs(i - myNumber) < closest:
            closest = i
    return closest
```

Comment: you could also return the index.

Comment: ! Incorrect ! Should be `if abs(myList[i] - myNumber) < abs(closest - myNumber): closest = myList[i];`. Better store that value beforehand though.

Comment: Surely the function as it stands already returns the index of the closest. For it to satisfy the requirements of the OP shouldn't the second last line read 
closest = myList[i]

Answer (score 4):

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]
```

## run it by using

```
price_near_to=find_nearest(df['Close'], df['Close'][-2])
```

Comment: what's `np` here?

Comment: @munmunbb It is [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/). It is a package for computing in python.

`import numpy as np`

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that Lauritz's suggestion idea of using bisect does not actually find the closest value in MyList to MyNumber. Instead, bisect finds the next value in *order* after MyNumber in MyList. So in OP's case you'd actually get the position of 44 returned instead of the position of 4.

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 4, 44, 88] 
>>> myNumber = 5
>>> pos = (bisect_left(myList, myNumber))
>>> myList[pos]
...
44
```

To get the value that's closest to 5 you could try converting the list to an array and using argmin from numpy like so.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> myNumber = 5   
>>> myList = [1, 3, 4, 44, 88] 
>>> myArray = np.array(myList)
>>> pos = (np.abs(myArray-myNumber)).argmin()
>>> myArray[pos]
...
4
```

I don't know how fast this would be though, my guess would be "not very".

Comment: Lauritz's function works correctly. You just using bisect_left only but Lauritz suggested a function takeClosest(...) that makes additional check.

Comment: If you're going to use NumPy, you could use `np.searchsorted` instead of `bisect_left`. And @Kanat is right - Lauritz's solution *does* include code which picks which of the two candidates is closer.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon Gustavo Lima's answer. The same thing can be done without creating an entirely new list. The values in the list can be replaced with the differentials as the `FOR` loop progresses.

```
def f_ClosestVal(v_List, v_Number):
"""Takes an unsorted LIST of INTs and RETURNS INDEX of value closest to an INT"""
for _index, i in enumerate(v_List):
    v_List[_index] = abs(v_Number - i)
return v_List.index(min(v_List))
```

> 

```
myList = [1, 88, 44, 4, 4, -2, 3]
v_Num = 5
print(f_ClosestVal(myList, v_Num)) ## Gives "3," the index of the first "4" in the list.
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may add to [@Lauritz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141511/9857220)

In order not to have a run error
don't forget to add a condition before the `bisect_left` line:

```
if (myNumber > myList[-1] or myNumber < myList[0]):
    return False
```

so the full code will look like:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def takeClosest(myList, myNumber):
    """
    Assumes myList is sorted. Returns closest value to myNumber.
    If two numbers are equally close, return the smallest number.
    If number is outside of min or max return False
    """
    if (myNumber > myList[-1] or myNumber < myList[0]):
        return False
    pos = bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    if pos == 0:
            return myList[0]
    if pos == len(myList):
            return myList[-1]
    before = myList[pos - 1]
    after = myList[pos]
    if after - myNumber < myNumber - before:
       return after
    else:
       return before
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def takeClosest(myList, myNumber):
    newlst = []
    for i in myList:
        newlst.append(i - myNumber)
    lstt = [abs(ele) for ele in newlst]
    print(myList[lstt.index(min(lstt))])

myList = [4, 1, 88, 44, 3]
myNumber = 5
takeClosest(myList,myNumber)
```

Comment: Do provide some explanation.