# Round a number to a given set of values

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

Talking Python 3 here.

I'm looking to round a number to a given set of values which can vary

Assume `value_set = [x, y, z]` and for the sake of the example `x, y, z = 1, 3.12, 4` I'm looking for a function that will round a given float to the closest number

`custom_round(0) --> 1`

`custom_round(2.7) --> 3.12`

Notice that it should be generic enough that `value_set` length will vary also

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)

Comment: Excatly what I needed

Answer (score 6):

You can use the min function in order to find the minimum in your list when the key is the absolute value of `x-n` (x is each item in the list).

```
value_set = [1, 3.12, 4]

def return_closest(n):
  return min(value_set, key=lambda x:abs(x-n))

number_to_check = 3
print (return_closest(number_to_check))

>>> 3.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by first sorting the list, and then use binary search:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class CustomRound:

    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.data = sorted(iterable)

    def __call__(self,x):
        data = self.data
        ndata = len(data)
        idx = bisect_left(data,x)
        if idx <= 0:
            return data[0]
        elif idx >= ndata:
            return data[ndata-1]
        x0 = data[idx-1]
        x1 = data[idx]
        if abs(x-x0) < abs(x-x1):
            return x0
        return x1
```

You can than construct your `CustomRound` like:

```
values = [1,3.12,4]
custom_round = CustomRound(values)
```

and simply call it:

```
>>> custom_round(0)
1
>>> custom_round(0.5)
1
>>> custom_round(1.5)
1
>>> custom_round(2.5)
3.12
>>> custom_round(3.12)
3.12
>>> custom_round(3.9)
4
>>> custom_round(4.1)
4
>>> custom_round(4.99)
4
```

This approach will work in ***O(log n)* for rounding** and ***O(n log n)* for construction**. So you will invest some additional time to construct the `custom_round`, but if you call it often, it will eventually pay off in rounding individual numbers.