# Error with FuzzyWuzzy: StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)

Tags: django, python-3.x, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

I cannot get the following function to run:

```
match, match_score = process.extractOne(score, pct_dict.keys())
```

I get a whitespace error I cannot seem to resolve.  Any idea what is causing this?

What it should do: If the score is 15 it should return 0.026

#### Error:

> Error: output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs) wnas1
>   |   File "/code/cleveland/templatetags/percentiles_ratings.py", line
>   32, in get_percentile_standard wnas1      |     match, match_score =
>   process.extractOne(score, pct_dict.keys()) wnas1      |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line
>   220, in extractOne wnas1      |     return max(best_list, key=lambda
>   i: i[1]) wnas1      |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/process.py", line
>   78, in extractWithoutOrder wnas1      |     processed_query =
>   processor(query) wnas1      |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/utils.py", line 95,
>   in full_process wnas1      |     string_out =
>   StringProcessor.replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace(s)
>   wnas1      |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fuzzywuzzy/string_processing.py",
>   line 26, in replace_non_letters_non_numbers_with_whitespace wnas1
>   |     return cls.regex.sub(" ", a_string)

#### Code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django import template
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process


register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def get_perc(score):
    MATCH_THRESHOLD = 80
    pct_dict = {14: 0.016, 14.7: 0.021, 15.3: 0.026, 16: 0.034, 16.7: 0.04, 17.3: 0.05, 18: 0.07, 18.7: 0.09,
                    19.3: 0.11, 20: 0.13, 20.7: 0.17, 21.3: 0.21, 22: 0.26, 22.7: 0.31, 23.3: 0.38, 24: 0.47}
    if not score:
        return '--'
    elif score < 26.7:
        return '<1'

    match, match_score = process.extractOne(score, pct_dict.keys())

    if match_score >= MATCH_THRESHOLD:
        return pct_dict[match]
    else:
        return '--'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#fuzzywuzzy) documentation, you need to compare between two strings. Meaning you need to convert you values in string to compare them. Then you need to do it like this:

```
match, match_score = process.extractOne(str(score), pct_dict.keys())
```

I would not recommend this approach because that will not be accurate.

```
>>> x = ['1','2','3']
>>> y='2'
>>> process.extractOne(y,x)
('2', 100)
>>> y='2.2'
>>> process.extractOne(y,x)
('2', 90)
>>> y = '2.9'
>>> process.extractOne(y,x)
('2', 90)
```

Here in last 2 entries, you will see score **90** for both 2.2 and 2.9, where 2.9 is much closer to 3.

As you have numbers and I would recommend you to do simply compare them like this:

```
value = min(pct_dict, key=lambda x:abs(x - score))
# then some logics to see if value is close to score or put some static threshold value like `abs(value-score) < .3`
```

There are few [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value) which might help you regarding this.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That was the solution.  I converted the data to string and the score value using str().  I will place my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked.  Thanks for the clarification regarding string values.  This allowed me to set str(score) to convert the score value to a string.

Here is the functioning code:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_perc(score):
    MATCH_THRESHOLD = 80
    pct_dict = {'14': '0.016', '14.7': '0.021', '15.3': '0.026', '16': '0.034', '16.7': '0.04', '17.3': '0.05', '18': '0.07', '18.7': '0.09', '19.3': '0.11', '20': '0.13', '20.7': '0.17', '21.3': '0.21', '22': '0.26', '22.7': '0.31', '23.3': '0.38', '24': '0.47'}
    if not score:
        return '--'
    elif score < 24:
        return '<1'

    match, match_score = process.extractOne(str(score), pct_dict.keys())

    if match_score >= MATCH_THRESHOLD:
        return pct_dict[match]
    else:
        return '--'
```