# Finding the x intercept of a function in the form of an array

Tags: python, arrays, math

I have an array of numbers that represents a function. I have times30 and positions30 which represent the time intervals and displacement intervals respectively. I do not have the exact equation for this function. I want to find the time this function crosses the x-axis for the first time, or even the time when the position30 number first comes closes to 0.

The function looks like:

[image]

You can see that the first x-intercept is between 0-5 seconds. But how can I find the exact value of time at that point? I read this post([from list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)) but my list shouldn't be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over pairs of `times[i-1]` and `times[i]` and find first such for which `positions[i-1]` and `positions[i]` have different sign.