# How find the nearest solution from a list

Tags: python, list

I would like know how I can find the nearest solution.

For example,  I have a list like it :

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

And ofc my list is really big ,  and I want find the nearest solution.

If I say  at my algorithm,  " find me the number 8"  But I have no number 8, so he will return me 7 because 7 is the nearest from 8.

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [from list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141150/from-list-of-integers-get-number-closest-to-a-given-value)

Answer (score 2):

```
min(list, key= lambda x: abs(solution - x))
```

this code returns the object in his list that his abs distance from the solution is the smallest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

target = 8
dist = [abs(i - target) for i in my_list]
min_index = dist.index(min(dist))
print(my_list[min_index])
```