# Scrolling/Zooming within a Plotwidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

i am playing around with a Plotwidget and i cant figure out how i can find the min-max positions from my list when zooming in and out.

Lets say i have a list which has 1000 values. When im scrolling/zooming i can only figure out the viewbox range and not the positions i am in my list.

Example:

- On init i am at x[0], x[1000]
- Scrolling once im at x[?], x[?]

Is it possible to find out the min-max index (if i am not directly on an index , whats the closest one)? I also would like to know, if it is possible to change the zooming factor when scrolling and can i set the viewbox padding to 0? I only figured out that u can change this with setXRange(..., padding=0)

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import pyqtgraph as pg

class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.graph = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graph)   
        self.graph.sigRangeChanged.connect(self.viewboxChanged)

        x = list()
        y = list()
        pos = 0
        for i in range(1000):
            r = randint(0,5)
            y.append(r)
            x.append(pos)
            pos +=r
        self.graph.plot(x, y)

    def viewboxChanged(self, view, range):
        print(range)
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Win()
    win.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more like how to interpret the values in your `range` variable. Note: Consider changing that variable name, because it can be confusing because there is a `python's built-in-function` called like that.

Your `range` variable has this structure:

```
[ [x_0, x_1], [y_0, y_1] ]
```

Where:

- `x_0` and `x_1` are the minimum and maximum values that are visible in the `x-axis`.
- `y_0` and `y_1` are the minimum and maximum values that are visible in the `y-axis`.

Now, what you want are the indexes, and that can be done using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141207/13929529). Finally, the implementation of all of the above in your code will look like this:

```py
class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.graph = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graph)   
        self.graph.sigRangeChanged.connect(self.viewboxChanged)
        ## Change the variables from local to an instance attribute
        ## to acces from the other functions
        self.x = list()
        self.y = list()
        pos = 0
        for i in range(1000):
            r = randint(0,5)
            self.y.append(r)
            self.x.append(pos)
            pos +=r
        self.graph.plot(self.x, self.y)

    def viewboxChanged(self, view, range_v):
        ## range_v[0] will return the list: [x_0, x_1]
        x0 = range_v[0][0]
        x1 = range_v[0][1]
        x0_index = min(self.x, key = lambda x: abs(x-x0))
        x1_index = min(self.x, key = lambda x: abs(x-x1))
        print(x0_index, x1_index)
        pass
```

There are comments inside explaining the changes I did.