# Finding number closest to cerain value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('54', '1.74', '253.2'), ('342', '2.85', '13.46'), ('53','2.43', '15.63')]
```

I want to find the tuple with item at position `[1]` closest to 2.0

I go like this:

```
number = lst[0][1]
for i in lst:
    if abs(float(i[1]) - 2) < float(number):
        number = i[1]
        if number in i:
            print i
```

But when I'm trying to convert the string to float it raises an exception ;/ How can I actually do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick ...

```
min(lst,key=lambda x: abs(float(x[0]) - 2))
```

The `min` function will compare each element in the list based on the `key` function.

demo:

```
>>> lst = [('1.74', '253.2'), ('2.85', '13.46'), ('2.43', '15.63')]
>>> min(lst,key=lambda x: abs(float(x[0]) - 2))
('1.74', '253.2')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. Something is however not working for me ;/. I'm scraping a website and my code looks like this: `lst = re.findall(pattern, html)` which produces a list of 3-item tuples `[('54', '1.74', '253.2'), ('342', '2.85', '13.46'), ('53','2.43', '15.63')]` going on `lst = min(lst,key=lambda x: abs(float(x[1] - 2))` and `print lst` I'm getting an `Invalid syntax` error. You know what's up here?

Comment: you've misplaced a paren. You need: `abs(float(x[1])-2)` instead of `abs(float(x[1] - 2))`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @Maus. You don't even know how much this got on my nerves lol :)

Comment: +1 for this very clean (and fast running) answer.  FWIW, this same approach can be used with *heapq.nsmallest()* to find the *n* closest values and with *sorted()* to rank order all of the inputs by their nearness to the target value.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- Thanks for the +1.  Coming from you it means a great deal :-).  And the `heapq` and `sorted` notes are good points.  It's beautiful how consistent the core language and the standard lib are in a number of places.