# Find Index That Matches To Closest Provided Number Pairing

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, min

I have a three individual lists in Python, all of which are quite large. A stipulation is that the lists ***cannot be*** reordered from how they are currently shown. A snippet of how each list looks is as follows:

`lats = [40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342]
 lons = [-74.32176109,-74.29518277,-74.26860445,-74.24202613,-74.21544781]
 data = [19,19,19,17,18]`

I am looking to provide a latitude and longitude pairing, and would like to return the index number and corresponding value of the `data` list that matches the closest to both the provided latitude and longitude.

For example, the pairing `40.9254, -74.2765` would return the corresponding index number, which would be the third set of values in the list snippet provided above.

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706041/finding-index-of-an-item-closest-to-the-value-in-a-list-thats-not-entirely-sort), I've been able to partition this search by individual list and return the corresponding index number. However, the index numbers are different.

Code:

`min(enumerate(lats), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-40.9254))
 min(enumerate(lons), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-(-74.2765)))`

`an index #, 40.92322342
a different index # than above, -74.26860445`

Are there any effective ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What does mean your *a different index # than above*? the `lats` contains identical values in your input

Comment: You need to define `matches the closest` in terms of *both* lat and lon. Maybe something like the sum of the absolute value of the differences. You can't look at them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first find the [euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between two points using `sqrt((x[0] - y[0]) ** 2 + (x[1] - y[1]) ** 2)`, then use it combined with [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) as a `key` to find the closest point.

```
from math import sqrt

lats = [40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342,40.92322342]
lons = [-74.32176109,-74.29518277,-74.26860445,-74.24202613,-74.21544781]

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return sqrt((x[0] - y[0]) ** 2 + (x[1] - y[1]) ** 2)

def find_closest_point(data, point):
    # create (point, index) pairs
    indices = ((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(data))

    # find smallest point, and only return the index
    return min(indices, key=lambda p: euclidean_distance(p[0], point))[1]

print(find_closest_point(zip(lats, lons), (40.9254, -74.2765)))
```

Which returns the third pair of coordinates(indexing starting at 0):

```
2
```

**Note:** You could have `lats` and `lons` in a list of tuples to begin with, then you don't need to call [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an object for Lattitude and Longitude.

```
class LatLong:

      def __init__(self, lat, lon):
          self.lat = lat
          self.lon = lon
```

Then create a single list of objects and for a given lat and long, just loop through the object list and return the object