# Get Number Closest To Value - If Multiple Closest, Get All - Python

Tags: python, list

I've seen [from list of integers, get number closest to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12141150/13710015) and [finding index of an item closest to the value in a list that's not entirely sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9706041/13710015), but neither of them cover how to find closest **values** if there are multiple.

Example:

```
>>> myList = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 12, 15, 17]
>>> min(myList, key=lambda x: abs(x - 16))
15  # How could I get both 17 and 15?
```

Comment: have you tried [`heapq.nsmallest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov could you post an answer with an example of using it! It would be very much appreciated! Thank you link also!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find more than 1 minimum value we can use [`heapq.nsmallest` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) like

```py
>>> myList = [1, 4, 5, 9, 10, 12, 15, 17]
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> nsmallest(2, myList, key=lambda x: abs(x - 16))
[15, 17]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a dictionary that maps distances to values, then return the values with the minimal distance like so:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

# {distance: [values]}
for i in myList:
    d[abs(i-16)].append(i)

d[min(d)] # Result: [15, 17]
```