# array of minimum euclidian distances between all points in array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I have this numpy array with points, something like

```
[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3), (x4,y4), (x5,y5)]
```

What I would like to do, is to get an array of all minimum distances.
So for point 1 `(x1, y1)`, I want the distance of the point closest to it, same for point 2 `(x2,y2)`, etc... 
Distance being `sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)`.

This will obviously be an array with the same length as my array with point (in this case: 5 points -> 5 minimum distances).

Any concise way of doing this without resorting to loops?

Comment: How much does performance matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10818546/2823755 looks promising

Comment: Or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: scipy.spatial.distance.cdist that is

Comment: What is the equivalent pure numpy solution is scipy can't be loaded for various reasons?  I have been using the norm approach but I have nothing to compare times to see whether pdist or cdist provide a really drastic improvement in process speeds considering point sets < 1000 or so

Comment: performance doesn't matter much, since this is a calculation done before the action starts. What you suggested, cel, does the trick nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution really focuses on readability over performance - It explicitly calculates and stores the whole `n x n` distance matrix and therefore cannot be considered efficient.

**But:** It is very concise and readable.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

#create n x d matrix (n=observations, d=dimensions)
A = np.array([[1,9,2,4], [1,2,3,1]]).T

# explicitly calculate the whole n x n distance matrix
dist_mat = squareform(pdist(A, metric="euclidean"))

# mask the diagonal
np.fill_diagonal(dist_mat, np.nan)

# and calculate the minimum of each row (or column)
np.nanmin(dist_mat, axis=1)
```