# python - Finding the vertices of the cuboid surrounding a coordinate in a cuboidal 3-d grid with non-regular spacings

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I will have a 3-d grid of points (defined by Cartesian vectors). For any given coordinate within the grid, I wish to find the 8 grid points making the cuboid which surrounds the given coordinate. I also need the distances between the vertices of the cuboid and the given coordinate. I have found a way of doing this for a meshgrid with regular spacings, but not for irregular spacings. I do not yet have an example of the irregularly spaced grid data, I just know that the algorithm will have to deal with them eventually. My solution for the regularly spaced points is based off of this post, [Finding index of nearest point in numpy arrays of x and y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818546/finding-index-of-nearest-point-in-numpy-arrays-of-x-and-y-coordinates) and is as follows:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:5, 0:10, 0:20]
# Example 3-d grid of points.

b = np.dstack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel()))[0]
tree = sp.spatial.cKDTree(b)
example_coord = np.array([1.5, 3.5, 5.5])    
d, i = tree.query((example_coord), 8)
# i being the indices of the closest grid points, d being their distance from the 
# given coordinate, example_coord

b[i[0]], d[0]
# This gives one of the points of the surrounding cuboid and its distance from
# example_coord
```

I am looking to make this algorithm run as efficiently as possible as it will need to be run a lot. Thanks in advance for your help.