# How to get the n-th nearest neighbor for each point in a NumPy array from the same array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array with shape (291336, 50). i.e. there are 291336 points where each point has 50 dimensions.

For each point in this array, I want to find the distance and index of its `k`th nearest neighbor by distance, belonging to the same array. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818546/finding-index-of-nearest-point-in-numpy-arrays-of-x-and-y-coordinates) related question, but it finds the `1st` nearest neighbor not the `k`th.

I have thought about using this brute force approach-

```
for i in X.shape[0]:
    distance_from_i = {}
    for j in X.shape[0]:
        store distance & index of j from i in distance_from_i
    sort distance_from_i and select the k'th point
```

But I know it's terrible. There must be a better way.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about sorting them once by distance from np.zeros(50)