# Using two dimensional coordinates for a time series in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

I am currently working with netcdf files. I want to plot a time series for a certain location.
So far I used:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('testing.nc')
lon_name = "lon"
lat_name = "lat"
time_name = "time"
point1 = {'x': 8.807176, 'y': 53.913996}

# Gets the closest point to the coordinates
df = ds.sel(lat=point1['y'], lon=point1['x'], method='nearest').to_dataframe()
```

This works fine, but now I got a dataset that uses two dimensional coordinates.
Using info() gives me this:

```
xarray.Dataset {
dimensions:
    ny = 536 ;
    nx = 532 ;
variables:
    datetime64[ns] time() ;
        time:standard_name = time ;
    float32 lat(ny, nx) ;
        lat:units = degrees_north ;
        lat:long_name = latitude ;
        lat:standard_name = latitude ;
    float32 lon(ny, nx) ;
        lon:units = degrees_east ;
        lon:long_name = longitude ;
        lon:standard_name = longitude ;
```

So how do I extract my data now in the easiest way? Using my code from above gives me "KeyError: 'no index found for coordinate lat'".
The coordinates I chose are inside the boundaries of the data. I assume that the problem is that the coordinates are two dimensional now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw that this was already asked somewhere else (which I didn't find before): [xarray select nearest lat/lon with multi-dimension coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758480/xarray-select-nearest-lat-lon-with-multi-dimension-coordinates?rq=1)