# how to optimize np.linalg.norm?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy-ufunc

I have the following function to compute distance between two points that are represented by matrices. i.e. points is a list of matrices, and other_points is an array of matrices.

```
def find_dist(points: list, other_points: np.array,) -> int:
    min_dists = [np.min(np.linalg.norm(other_points - i, axis=1), axis=0) for i in points]
```

Is there a better way to achieve the above to optimize performance? I tried to use np.ufunc.outer as following but the logic gets messed up. I am not sure how to use np.ufunc.outer to achieve the above:

```
   min_dists = [np.min(np.subtract.outer(other_points, i), axis=0) for i in points]
```

Thanks!

Comment: since you need to compute minimal distance you do not need to compute all distances, you can calculate dot product, find smallest and calculate its square root. Side note: why you do not represent all `points` as `np.array`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the data points are from the MNIST dataset, for example, so I wouldn't be able to find the dot product between two matrices. Am I missing something? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding index of nearest point in numpy arrays of x and y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818546/finding-index-of-nearest-point-in-numpy-arrays-of-x-and-y-coordinates)