# Get coordinates of mouse click in matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, onclick, mouseevent

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook where I have a `numpy.stack` of raster files with values between -1 and +1, which shape is as follows:

```
files.shape
(2, 766, 1398)
```

I am ploting one of them with:

```
plt.imshow(files[0], cmap="RdYlGn")
```

My objective is to ask the user to click somewhere in the image displayed with `matplotlib`. When doing so, I want to store the array coordinates of the click event so that I can extract the pixel value at that location using:

```
 values = files.sample(zip(Xc, Yc))
```

Looking for previous posts on this forum I found [Store mouse click event coordinates with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521120/store-mouse-click-event-coordinates-with-matplotlib/25525143) but I am not managing to implement the proposed example.

Any help on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not managing to implement the proposed example"? Can you copy that code and run it? Or not? What's the problem?

Comment: When I copy that code in my Jupyter Notebook and try to make it work with the example they provide, I cannot manage the get the list of coordinates. The `coords` variable remains empty even after doing more than 2 clicks, which is the limit they put. I have tried to adapt their suggestion to my case but not working neither

Comment: Ok, so don't mix things up. First step is to get the solution from the other post working; as long as it doesn't work for you there is no point in adapting it to your case.

Comment: As I am trying to get the coords using a raster array and not a plot I think my case is different as the one in the example. I want to know if that same approach would work and how. Trying to adapt it but not getting any result