# Matplotlib: click events , when click see only a hand

Tags: matplotlib, events, click

like many others I like to get the x,y coordinates in a plot, with a mouse click.

I looked at turorials and also stack overflow questions and answers.
copy some example code, works, i see plots, but when I  mouse click on a plot, I only see a little hand and nothing happens.
the mouse click event does not start.
tried Native python code for mouse event on the whole screen, this works, but not in matplotlib.

thanks for the answer.

kind regards.

Willie.

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried if you want anybody to help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521120/store-mouse-click-event-coordinates-with-matplotlib