# How to draw lines between mouseclicks on a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591214/8565438) shows an excellent way of getting coordinates of mouse clicks on a matplotlib plot using [mpl_point_clicker](https://mpl-point-clicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

With a few clicks and this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_point_clicker import clicker

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot(np.sin(np.arange(200)/(5*np.pi)))
klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"])

plt.show()

print(klicker.get_positions())
```

I am able to produce this plot:

[image]

and this textual output:

```
{'event': array([[ 5.83720666e+00, -5.73988654e-01],
       [ 2.46956149e+01, -1.41575199e-02],
       [ 5.20403030e+01,  5.70227612e-01],
       [ 8.55139728e+01,  7.56837990e-01],
       [ 1.30302686e+02,  3.73795635e-01],
       [ 1.69433877e+02, -2.40054293e-01],
       [ 2.01493167e+02, -5.05237462e-01]])}
```

which I can use to produce this plot:

[image]

with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_point_clicker import clicker

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot(np.sin(np.arange(200)/(5*np.pi)))
klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"])

data = \
np.array([[ 5.83720666e+00, -5.73988654e-01],
         [ 2.46956149e+01, -1.41575199e-02],
         [ 5.20403030e+01,  5.70227612e-01],
         [ 8.55139728e+01,  7.56837990e-01],
         [ 1.30302686e+02,  3.73795635e-01],
         [ 1.69433877e+02, -2.40054293e-01],
         [ 2.01493167e+02, -5.05237462e-01]])

plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1],c='r')


plt.show()

print(klicker.get_positions())
```

However, I would like to draw this line as I am clicking on the plot. Ie instead of points drawn when I click on the graph on the first plot, I would like to have a line drawn between the points I click. I'd like the end result look similar to my second plot, but without needing a second script to create that plot. If I click at some new place on the plot, the red line should extend to this new location. As text output, I would like to have the coordinates of my clicks, just like in the examples above.

**How can I achieve this in Python?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [API](https://mpl-point-clicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autoapi/mpl_point_clicker._clicker.clicker.html) says:
`**line_kwargs (kwargs) – Line2D objects (from ax.plot) are used to generate the markers. line_kwargs will be passed through to all of the ax.plot calls.`
So, let's set the linestyle:

```
klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"], **{"linestyle": "--"})
```

Sample output:
[image]

Other Line2D keywords can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html?highlight=line2d#matplotlib.lines.Line2D).

Comment: You don't need to make a dict and expand it for kwargs to work. A slightly simpler version would be: `klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"], linestyle= "--")`