# Search for closest value in list of lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, grid

I have an list of lists :

```
[[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 2], [4, 5]]
```

and a value in a list, for example : `[4,0]`

Imagine this to be xy-grid and i would like to find the closest value in the list of lists as possible.
I have looked here [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)
more exactly this line : `idx = np.array([np.linalg.norm(x+y) for (x,y)` in array-`value]).argmin()`

The problem is that it sum up x+y, so it would say that [1,3] is the closest one and it could be true in some cases but not all and in this specific case [3,2] is closer.

Please help.

Comment: So why is `[1, 3]` not the closet is all cases? Can you provide us with examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [4]: arr = np.array([[0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 2], [4, 5]])

In [5]: value = np.array([4,0])

In [6]: np.linalg.norm(arr-value, axis=1)
Out[6]: array([ 4.47213595,  4.24264069,  5.38516481,  2.23606798,  5.        ])

In [7]: np.linalg.norm(arr-value, axis=1).argmin()
Out[7]: 3

In [8]: arr[np.linalg.norm(arr-value, axis=1).argmin()]
Out[8]: array([3, 2])
```

Note that if `arr` is very large and you need to compute the point in `arr` closest to many other points, it is more efficient to use a [KDTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) since once you have the data in the KDTree (which takes O(n log n) time), searching for the nearest point requires only O(log n) time. Using `arr[norm(...).argmin()]` requires O(n) time.

So if you have scipy, you could find the nearest point like this:

```
In [22]: from scipy import spatial

In [23]: tree = spatial.KDTree(arr)

In [24]: distances, indices = tree.query([4, 0])

In [25]: tree.data[indices]
Out[25]: array([3, 2])
```