# Vectorizing a function that finds the nearest value in an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've written the following function:

```
import numpy as np


def _find_nearest(array, value):
    """Find the index in array whose element is nearest to value.

    Parameters
    ----------
    array : np.array
      The array.

    value : number
      The value.

    Returns
    -------
    integer
      The index in array whose element is nearest to value.

    """
    if array.argmax() == array.size - 1 and value > array.max():
        return array.size
    return (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
```

I'd like to vectorize this function, so that I can pass several values at once.  That is, I'd like to have `value` be an array, and have `_find_nearest` return, rather than a single index, the indices for each of the values in the submitted `value_array`.

Can anyone see a way to do this?

Comment: Add another dimension (```np.newaxis```) to the array being searched then broadcast  across the new dimension.

Comment: Given huge arrays, broadcasting might waste a lot of memory with repeated data.

Comment: @Kartik, 'waste' is pretty subjective, how about consume.  Sometimes you trade time for space and space for time.

Comment: Consume it is. I agree with you.

Comment: See if this helps : [`Find elements of array one nearest to elements of array two`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841654/find-elements-of-array-one-nearest-to-elements-of-array-two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the parent function, where both the `value` and the `array` are visible, you can use a `lambda` to enable the vectorization. I shall call the parent function `main`

```
def main():
    value = np.random.rand(10, 1)
    array = np.random.rand(100, 100)
    vec_nearest = lambda x: _find_nearest(array, x)
    np.vectorize(vec_nearest)(value)
```

This will work on one `array`, and multiple values of `vector`. The return will be an array.