# How to select value from array that is closest to value in array using vectorization?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have an array of values that I want to replace with from an array of choices based on which choice is linearly closest.

The catch is the size of the choices is defined at runtime.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [4, 4, 4], [9, 9, 9]])
choices = np.array([1, 5, 10])
```

If choices was static in size, I would simply use np.where

```
d = np.where(np.abs(a - choices[0]) > np.abs(a - choices[1]), 
      np.where(np.abs(a - choices[0]) > np.abs(a - choices[2]), choices[0], choices[2]),
         np.where(np.abs(a - choices[1]) > np.abs(a - choices[2]), choices[1], choices[2]))
```

To get the output:

```
>>d
>>[[1, 1, 1], [5, 5, 5], [10, 10, 10]]
```

Is there a way to do this more dynamically while still preserving the vectorization.

Comment: Subtract ```choices``` from ```a``` find the index of the minimum of the result, substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract choices from `a`, find the index of the minimum of the result, substitute.

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [4, 4, 4], [9, 9, 9]])
choices = np.array([1, 5, 10])
b = a[:,:,None] - choices
np.absolute(b,b)
i = np.argmin(b, axis = -1)
a = choices[i]
print a

>>> 
[[ 1  1  1]
 [ 5  5  5]
 [10 10 10]]

a = np.array([[0, 3, 0], [4, 8, 4], [9, 1, 9]])
choices = np.array([1, 5, 10])
b = a[:,:,None] - choices
np.absolute(b,b)
i = np.argmin(b, axis = -1)
a = choices[i]
print a

>>>    
[[ 1  1  1]
 [ 5 10  5]
 [10  1 10]]
>>>
```

---

The extra dimension was added to `a` so that each element of `choices` would be subtracted from each element of `a`. `choices` was [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) against `a` in the third dimension, [This link has a decent graphic](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting). `b.shape` is (3,3,3).  [EricsBroadcastingDoc](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) is a pretty good explanation and has a graphic 3-d example at the end.

For the second example:

```
>>> print b
[[[ 1  5 10]
  [ 2  2  7]
  [ 1  5 10]]

 [[ 3  1  6]
  [ 7  3  2]
  [ 3  1  6]]

 [[ 8  4  1]
  [ 0  4  9]
  [ 8  4  1]]]
>>> print i
[[0 0 0]
 [1 2 1]
 [2 0 2]]
>>>
```

The final assignment uses an [Index Array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) or [Integer Array Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

In the second example, notice that there was a *tie* for element `a[0,1]` , either one or five could have been substituted.

Comment: so to see if I'm understanding the idea is make choices the same shape as A?  so what if A was something like a 10x10?

Comment: @dranobob, see edit - hopefully that clears it up.  If ```a``` was originally (10,10) then ```b``` would have been (1010,3).  We created a third dimension for ```a``` that ```choices``` could be broadcast against.

Answer (score 2):

To explain wwii's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712936/525169) in a little more detail:

The idea is to create a new dimension which does the job of comparing each element of `a` to each element in `choices` using [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). This is easily done for an arbitrary number of dimensions in `a` using the [ellipsis syntax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing):

```
>>> b = np.abs(a[..., np.newaxis] - choices)
array([[[ 1,  5, 10],
        [ 1,  5, 10],
        [ 1,  5, 10]],
       [[ 3,  1,  6],
        [ 3,  1,  6],
        [ 3,  1,  6]],
       [[ 8,  4,  1],
        [ 8,  4,  1],
        [ 8,  4,  1]]])
```

Taking `argmin` along the axis you just created (the last axis, with label -1) gives you the desired index in `choices` that you want to substitute:

```
>>> np.argmin(b, axis=-1)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Which finally allows you to choose those elements from `choices`:

```
>>> d = choices[np.argmin(b, axis=-1)]
>>> d
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [10, 10, 10]])
```

---

**For a non-symmetric shape:**

Let's say `a` had shape `(2, 5)`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape((2, 5))
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Then you'd get:

```
>>> b = np.abs(a[..., np.newaxis] - choices)
>>> b
array([[[ 1,  5, 10],
        [ 0,  4,  9],
        [ 1,  3,  8],
        [ 2,  2,  7],
        [ 3,  1,  6]],

       [[ 4,  0,  5],
        [ 5,  1,  4],
        [ 6,  2,  3],
        [ 7,  3,  2],
        [ 8,  4,  1]]])
```

This is hard to read, but what it's saying is, `b` has shape:

```
>>> b.shape
(2, 5, 3)
```

The first two dimensions came from the shape of `a`, which is also `(2, 5)`. The last dimension is the one you just created. To get a better idea:

```
>>> b[:, :, 0]  # = abs(a - 1)
array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
>>> b[:, :, 1]  # = abs(a - 5)
array([[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> b[:, :, 2]  # = abs(a - 10)
array([[10,  9,  8,  7,  6],
       [ 5,  4,  3,  2,  1]])
```

Note how `b[:, :, i]` is the absolute difference between `a` and `choices[i]`, for each `i = 1, 2, 3`.

Hope that helps explain this a little more clearly.

Comment: How would this change if the dimensions were way off, like A was 17 x 7?

Comment: @dranobob It won't change at all. For extremely large array sizes, your program could take up a lot of memory. But for 17x7, you wouldn't need to worry

Comment: @dranobob In fact, it wouldn't even change if your `a` matrix had shape (4,) or (12, 7, 8) or anything like that, since the ellipsis takes care, no matter how many dimensions `a` has.

Comment: This is very cool, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around vectorization concepts.   Can you help me visualize how such an odd A matrix would work in this setup. I can easily picture the 3x3

Comment: I'm going to keep staring at this till it make sense.  I've been coding all weekend so its possible I might need to take a stab at it in the morning :)

Answer (score 2):

I love [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and would have gone that way myself too. But, with large arrays, I would like to suggest another approach with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) that keeps it memory efficient and thus achieves performance benefits, like so -

```
def searchsorted_app(a, choices):
    lidx = np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'left').clip(max=choices.size-1)
    ridx = (np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'right')-1).clip(min=0)
    cl = np.take(choices,lidx) # Or choices[lidx]
    cr = np.take(choices,ridx) # Or choices[ridx]
    mask = np.abs(a - cl) > np.abs(a - cr)
    cl[mask] = cr[mask]
    return cl
```

Please note that if the elements in `choices` are not sorted, we need to add in the additional argument `sorter` with `np.searchsorted`.

Runtime test -

```
In [160]: # Setup inputs
     ...: a = np.random.rand(100,100)
     ...: choices = np.sort(np.random.rand(100))
     ...: 

In [161]: def broadcasting_app(a, choices): # @wwii's solution
     ...:     return choices[np.argmin(np.abs(a[:,:,None] - choices),-1)]
     ...: 

In [162]: np.allclose(broadcasting_app(a,choices),searchsorted_app(a,choices))
Out[162]: True

In [163]: %timeit broadcasting_app(a, choices)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.3 ms per loop

In [164]: %timeit searchsorted_app(a, choices)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.78 ms per loop
```

Related post : [Find elements of array one nearest to elements of array two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841654/find-elements-of-array-one-nearest-to-elements-of-array-two)

Comment: In the case of a tie (integer arrays), your's favors the *right* index while mine favors the *left*.  OP didn't comment when I pointed out the tie behavior.  I guess if the arrays are floats the likelihood of ties would be minimal.

Comment: Interesting, it seems the performance difference varies with the size of ```choices``` but not with the size of ```a```.

Comment: @wwii Ties with the indices? I guess with the final indexing step of `choices[i]`, the selected values would be the same either way, right? Hmm, well I took the shapes representative of what OP had in sample, i.e. `choices.size = n` and `a.shape = (n,n)`.

Comment: In my second example, ```a[0,1]``` is three which is equidistant from two of the choices, one and five.  That is what I am calling a tie, Either one or five could be substituted per the OP's spec -both are correct. Your method chooses five and mine chooses one. But this probably only happens when the inputs are integer arrays.  I like the way yours works, I'm certainly not in the habit of thinking that way.

Comment: @wwii Ah I see now! Well OP needs to take a call on those cases then because not specified .