# Selecting close matches from one array based on another reference array

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, similarity

I have an array `A` and a reference array `B`. Size of `A` is at least as big as `B`. e.g.

```
A = [2,100,300,793,1300,1500,1810,2400]
B = [4,305,789,1234,1890]
```

`B` is in fact the position of peaks in a signal at a specified time, and `A` contains position of peaks at a later time. But some of the elements in `A` are actually not the peaks I want (might be due to noise, etc), and I want to find the 'real' one in `A` based on `B`. The 'real' elements in `A` should be close to those in `B`, and in the example given above, the 'real' ones in `A` should be `A'=[2,300,793,1300,1810]`. It should be obvious in this example that `100,1500,2400` are not the ones we want as they are quite far off from any of the elements in B. How can I code this in the most efficient/accurate way in python/matlab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach #1:** With [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we can look for absolute element-wise subtractions between the input arrays and use an appropriate threshold to filter out unwanted elements from `A`. It seems for the given sample inputs, a threshold of `90` works.

Thus, we would have an implementation, like so -

```
thresh = 90
Aout = A[(np.abs(A[:,None] - B) < thresh).any(1)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [69]: A
Out[69]: array([   2,  100,  300,  793, 1300, 1500, 1810, 2400])

In [70]: B
Out[70]: array([   4,  305,  789, 1234, 1890])

In [71]: A[(np.abs(A[:,None] - B) < 90).any(1)]
Out[71]: array([   2,  300,  793, 1300, 1810])
```

**Approach #2:** Based on [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40716474/3293881), here's a memory efficient approach using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), which could be crucial for large arrays -

```
def searchsorted_filter(a, b, thresh):
    choices = np.sort(b) # if b is already sorted, skip it
    lidx = np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'left').clip(max=choices.size-1)
    ridx = (np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'right')-1).clip(min=0)
    cl = np.take(choices,lidx) # Or choices[lidx]
    cr = np.take(choices,ridx) # Or choices[ridx]
    return a[np.minimum(np.abs(a - cl), np.abs(a - cr)) < thresh]
```

Sample run -

```
In [95]: searchsorted_filter(A,B, thresh = 90)
Out[95]: array([   2,  300,  793, 1300, 1810])
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
In [104]: A = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100000,(1000)))

In [105]: B = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,100000,(400)))

In [106]: out1 = A[(np.abs(A[:,None] - B) < 10).any(1)]

In [107]: out2 = searchsorted_filter(A,B, thresh = 10)

In [108]: np.allclose(out1, out2)  # Verify results
Out[108]: True

In [109]: %timeit A[(np.abs(A[:,None] - B) < 10).any(1)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop

In [110]: %timeit searchsorted_filter(A,B, thresh = 10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.3 µs per loop
```

---

**Jan 2018 Update with further performance boost**

We can avoid the second usage of `np.searchsorted(..., 'right')` by making use of the indices obtained from `np.searchsorted(..., 'left')` and also the `absolute` computations, like so -

```
def searchsorted_filter_v2(a, b, thresh):
    N = len(b)

    choices = np.sort(b) # if b is already sorted, skip it

    l = np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'left')
    l_invalid_mask = l==N
    l[l_invalid_mask] = N-1
    left_offset = choices[l]-a
    left_offset[l_invalid_mask] *= -1    

    r = (l - (left_offset!=0))
    r_invalid_mask = r<0
    r[r_invalid_mask] = 0
    r += l_invalid_mask
    right_offset = a-choices[r]
    right_offset[r_invalid_mask] *= -1

    out = a[(left_offset < thresh) | (right_offset < thresh)]
    return out
```

Updated timings to test the further speedup -

```
In [388]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,1000000,(100000))
     ...: B = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,1000000,(40000)))
     ...: np.random.shuffle(B)
     ...: thresh = 10
     ...: 
     ...: out1 = searchsorted_filter(A, B, thresh)
     ...: out2 = searchsorted_filter_v2(A, B, thresh)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
True

In [389]: %timeit searchsorted_filter(A, B, thresh)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [390]: %timeit searchsorted_filter_v2(A, B, thresh)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.9 ms per loop
```

Digging deeper -

```
In [396]: a = A; b = B

In [397]: N = len(b)
     ...: 
     ...: choices = np.sort(b) # if b is already sorted, skip it
     ...: 
     ...: l = np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'left')

In [398]: %timeit np.sort(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 2 ms per loop

In [399]: %timeit np.searchsorted(choices, a, 'left')
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 ms per loop
```

Seems like `searchsorted` and `sort` are taking almost all of the runtime and they seem essential to this method. So, doesn't seem like it could be improved any further staying with this sort-based approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could find the distance of each point in `A` from each value in `B` using `bsxfun` and then find the index of the point in `A` which is closest to each value in `B` using `min`.

```
[dists, ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, B.')), [], 2)
```

If you're on R2016b, `bsxfun` can be removed thanks to automatic broadcasting

```
[dists, ind] = min(abs(A - B.'), [], 2);
```

If you suspect that some values in `B` are not real peaks, then you can set a threshold value and remove any distances that were greater than this value.

```
threshold = 90;
ind = ind(dists < threshold);
```

Then we can use `ind` to index into `A`

```
output = A(ind);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MATLAB [interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function that exactly does what you want.
option `nearest` is used to find nearest points and there is no need to specify a threshold.

```
out = interp1(A, A, B, 'nearest', 'extrap');
```

comparing with other method:

```
A = sort(randi([0,1000000],1,10000));

B = sort(randi([0,1000000],1,4000));

disp('---interp1----------------')
tic
    out = interp1(A, A, B, 'nearest', 'extrap');
toc
disp('---subtraction with threshold------')
%numpy version is the same
tic
    [dists, ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, B.')), [], 2);
toc
```

**Result**:

```
---interp1----------------
Elapsed time is 0.00778699 seconds.
---subtraction with threshold------
Elapsed time is 0.445485 seconds.
```

`interp1` can be used for inputs larger than 10000 and 4000 but in `subtrction` method out of memory error occured.

Comment: So, it assumes that two values from `A` can't be close to one element in `B`?  Like if `A(2)` were `5` instead?

Comment: @Divakar if A(2)==5 then result becomes `[5    300    793   1300   1810]` ,so always interpolated to nearest neighbors. if I get what you are saying

Comment: Well I was referring to the question itself as it stated - `".... are not the ones we want as they are quite far off from any of the elements in B"`. So, I thought OP needed a threshold there to signify that "quite far" criteria. So, with it, both `2` and `5` from `A` have to be included as they are "quite close by" to the `4` in `B`. Maybe OP won't have two such elements that are that close enough to cause any such conflict.