# Given two lists of ints, how can we find the closes number in one list from the other one?

Tags: python

Given I have two different lists with ints.

`a = [1, 4, 11, 20, 25]` and `b = [3, 10, 20]`

I want to return a list of length `len(b)` that stores the closest number in `a` for each ints in `b`.

So, this should return `[4, 11, 20]`.

I can do this in brute force, but what is a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT: It would be great if I can do this with standard library, if needed, only.

Comment: Can be repeat? I mean if `a = [1, 2]` , `b=[3, 3]` , will be return `[2, 2]` or `[1, 2]`?

Comment: There can be repeats

Comment: Are the lists `a`, `b` already sorted?

Comment: Nope. Not necessarily sorted.

Comment: What was your brute-force way?

Comment: Sort a: nlog(n). For each element in b, do a binary search on a where "if not found, return the closest": mlog(n). So instead of a brute force of n*m, you can achieve max(m,n)*log(n).

Comment: @sideshowbarker This question seems to be quite clear. I do not understand the reason for putting this on hold.

Comment: The most performant answer is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350318/8033585 (a possible duplicate question as well) Beats my solution by a large factor. CC: @jpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1, 4, 11, 20, 25]
>>> b = [3, 10, 20]
>>> 
>>> ans = list(map(lambda y:min(a, key=lambda x:abs(x-y)),b))
>>> ans
[4, 11, 20]
```

It's a loop for the question 'get number closest given a value'

```
value = #number
min(a, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))
```

Comment: Note this is still brute force.

Comment: This solution is a more handsome version of nested loops. It may even be slower than that, may need to be tested.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a more optimal solution is to use K-D Trees:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
def agn_val(a, b):
    """ Return **values** in a closest to the values in b """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    tr = cKDTree(a[:, None])
    return a[tr.query(np.atleast_2d(b).T)[1]].tolist()

def agn_idx(a, b):
    """ Return **indices of values** in a closest to the values in b """
    tr = cKDTree(np.atleast_2d(a).T)
    return tr.query(np.atleast_2d(b).T)[1].tolist()
```

#### Timings:

Below I use a test similar to @eugenhu except I increase the input list sizes (tests with small input lists are not accurate).

Also, let's define @jpp function:

```
def jpp(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    return [a[np.abs(a - i).argmin()] for i in b]
```

**NOTE:** At the expense of memory usage, the following variation of @jpp function is somewhat faster:

```
def jpp2(a, b):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    return a[np.argmin(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a, b)), axis=0)]
```

I have also found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350318/8033585 that returns indices (like `agn_idx()`). A modified version that returns *values* is:

```
def closest_val(a, b):
    B = np.asarray(a)
    A = np.asarray(b)
    # original code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350318/8033585:
    L = B.size
    sidx_B = B.argsort()
    sorted_B = B[sidx_B]
    sorted_idx = np.searchsorted(sorted_B, A)
    sorted_idx[sorted_idx==L] = L-1
    mask = (sorted_idx > 0) & \
    ((np.abs(A - sorted_B[sorted_idx-1]) < np.abs(A - sorted_B[sorted_idx])) )
    return B[sidx_B[sorted_idx-mask]]
```

Then I generate a sample:

```
random.seed(0) # for repeatability
a = random.sample(range(1, 10000), 500) # a contains unique values
b = [random.randint(0, 10000) for i in range(1000)]
```

Now timings:

```
In [65]: %timeit f(a, b)
113 ms ± 1.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [66]: %timeit g(a, b)
72.7 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [67]: %timeit jpp(a, b)
3.15 ms ± 111 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [68]: %timeit jpp2(a, b)
1.69 ms ± 23.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [69]: %timeit agn_val(a, b)
934 µs ± 9.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [70]: %timeit closest_val(a, b)
144 µs ± 3.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partially vectorised (but still brute force) solution with NumPy. You should see large performance improvements versus any brute-force list-based method. Via sorting you can achieve O(*n* log *n*) time complexity, e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41856629/9209546).

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 4, 11, 20, 25])
b = np.array([3, 10, 20])

res = [a[np.abs(a - i).argmin()] for i in b]

# [4, 11, 20]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without numpy?

Comment: @Dawn17, Probably. But that wasn't your question: `I can do this in brute force, but what is a more efficient way to do this?` NumPy is a good way to *avoid* or *optimise* brute-force methods.

Comment: Sorry. Would be great if you can help me doing without it.

Comment: _"Would be great if you can help me doing without it."_ @Dawn17 Why?

Comment: At the expense of memory usage, here is a variation that is somewhat faster: `a = np.asarray(a); return a[np.argmin(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(a, b)), axis=0)]`

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to sort `a`, `b` first, for each `b[i]`, find the closest element in `a`, call this `a[j_i]`; then throw away the elements smaller than `a[j_i]` (i.e. `a=a[j_i:]`), repeat for `b[i+1]`. Use whatever algorithm you want to find the closest element in `a` to a given value:

```
a = [1, 4, 11, 20, 25]
b = [3, 10, 20]

a_tmp = sorted(a)

# Sort `b` but keep a record of each element's original index.
b_tmp = sorted(enumerate(b), key=lambda x: x[1])

# Initialise an 'empty' output array.
out = [None]*len(b)

for i, v in b_tmp:
    # Throw away elements in `a_tmp` smaller than the "current closest element to `v`"
    # (`v` is the current element of `b` being considered) since they can't possibly
    # be closer to the next larger element in `b` than the
    # "current closest element to `v`".
    a_tmp = a_tmp[min(enumerate(a_tmp),
                      key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-v))[0]:]
    out[i] = a_tmp[0]

print(out)
```

The 'brute force' method `list(map(lambda y:min(a, key=lambda x:abs(x-y)),b))` ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799016/8944057)) will be faster for small `a`, `b` lists (around `len(a)=10`, `len(b)=5`) since (I believe) it doesn't carry the overhead of first sorting the input lists.

**Timings:**

```
import random

param = 10000
a = [random.randint(-100*param,100*param) for i in range(param)]
b = [random.randint(-100*param,100*param) for i in range(param//100)]

def f(a,b):
    return [min(a, key=lambda x:abs(x-y)) for y in b]

def g(a,b):
    a = sorted(a)
    ib = sorted(enumerate(b), key=lambda x: x[1])
    out = [None]*len(b)

    for i, b_i in ib:
        a = a[min(enumerate(a),key=lambda ia: abs(ia[1]-b_i))[0]:]
        out[i] = a[0]

    return out

%timeit f(a,b)
%timeit g(a,b)
```

```
285 ms ± 26.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
172 ms ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

**Using Numpy**

```
import random
import numpy as np

param = 10000
a = [random.randint(-100*param,100*param) for i in range(param)]
b = [random.randint(-100*param,100*param) for i in range(param//100)]

# `f_np()` and `g_np()` expect regular Python lists as arguments and convert them
# to numpy arrays internally, returning the results as Python lists.

def f_np(a,b):  # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52798995/8944057
    a = np.array(a)
    b = np.array(b)
    return [a[np.abs(a - i).argmin()] for i in b]

def g_np(a,b):
    a = np.sort(a)
    b_idx = np.argsort(b)
    out = [None]*len(b)

    for i in b_idx:
        a = a[np.abs(a - b[i]).argmin():]
        out[i] = a[0]

    return out

%timeit f_np(a,b)
%timeit g_np(a,b)
```

```
3.47 ms ± 105 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.82 ms ± 149 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

is a lot faster, even the equivalent 'brute force' method is many times faster. But if you're going to open up yourself to other libraries then also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52799252/8944057).

Answer (score 0):

Use binary search, assuming the lists are in order.

The brute force in this case is only O(n), so I wouldn't worry about it, just use brute force.

EDIT:
yeh it is O(len(a)*len(b)) (roughly O(n^2)
sorry stupid mistake.

Since these aren't necessarily sorted the fastest is still O(len(a)*len(b)) though. Sorting the lists (using timsort) would take O(nlogn), then binary search O(logn), which results in O(nlog^2n)*O(n)=O(n^2log^2n), which is slower then just O(n^2).

Comment: Brute force is O(len(a) * len(b))

Comment: This is the only solution which suggests (in very raw terms) a way to avoid O(*mn*) time complexity.

Comment: You wouldn't multiply the time it takes to sort `a` by the time it takes to find the closest elements in `a` from `b` yeah? It should just be O(#a log #a) + O(#b log #a) since you're not sorting it each time you do the search.

Comment: yeh you're right. I need to stop multiplying things haha.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity can be **O(nlgn)** using `lower_bound`. (The function from cpp, it use binary search to find element in sorted array).

I didn't find available and suitable `lower_bound` function in python. So implement it directly.

```
def lower_bound(sequence, value, compare):
    elements = len(sequence)
    offset = 0
    middle = 0
    found = len(sequence)

    while elements > 0:
        middle = elements >> 1
        if compare(value, sequence[offset + middle]) > 0:
            offset = offset + middle + 1
            elements = elements - (middle + 1)
        else:
            found = offset + middle
            elements = middle
    return found
```

Then invoke it as `lower_bound`:

```
a = [1, 4, 11, 20, 25]
b = [3, 10, 20]

a.sort()
re_a = a[::-1]

[min([a[lower_bound(a, i, lambda x,y: x > y) % len(a)], re_a[lower_bound(re_a, i, lambda x, y: x < y) % len(re_a)]], key=lambda num:abs(num-i)) for i in b]
# [4, 11, 20]
```

In every Iteration of b, find **the first element bigger or equals** to element and find **the first element smaller or equals** to element, then compare them and select suitable one.

So the time complexity will be **O(nlgn)**, better than using brute force.