# find and replace closest values in a numpy array with respect to second array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 2D `np.array` (`vec`).
I would like to replace each value in `vec` with the closest value from a shorter array `vals`.

I have tried the following

```
replaced_vals=vals[np.argmin(np.abs(vec[:, np.newaxis] - vals), axis=0)]
```

but it does not work because the size of `vec` and `vals` are different.

Example input

```
vec = np.array([10.1,10.7,11.4,102,1100]
vals = np.array([10.0,11.0,100.0])
```

Desired output:

```
replaced_vals = [10.0,11.0,11.0,100.0,100.0]
```

Comment: [`Memory efficient solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350318/) - `vals[closest_argmin(vec,vals)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `vals` array is sorted, a more memory efficient, and possibly generally more efficient, solution is possible via [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
def jpp(vec, vals):
    ss = np.searchsorted(vals, vec)
    a = vals[ss - 1]
    b = vals[np.minimum(len(vals) - 1, ss)]
    return np.where(np.fabs(vec - a) < np.fabs(vec - b), a, b)

vec = np.array([10.1,10.7,11.4,102,1100])
vals = np.array([10.0,11.0,100.0])

print(jpp(vec, vals))

[  10.   11.   11.  100.  100.]
```

#### Performance benchmarking

```
# Python 3.6.0, NumPy 1.11.3

n = 10**6
vec = np.array([10.1,10.7,11.4,102,1100]*n)
vals = np.array([10.0,11.0,100.0])

# @ThomasPinetz's solution, memory inefficient
def tho(vec, vals):
    return vals[np.argmin(np.abs(vec[:, np.newaxis] - vals), axis=1)]

def jpp(vec, vals):
    ss = np.searchsorted(vals, vec)
    a = vals[ss - 1]
    b = vals[np.minimum(len(vals) - 1, ss)]
    return np.where(np.fabs(vec - a) < np.fabs(vec - b), a, b)

# @Divakar's solution, adapted from first related Q&A link
def diva(A, B):
    L = B.size
    sorted_idx = np.searchsorted(B, A)
    sorted_idx[sorted_idx==L] = L-1
    mask = (sorted_idx > 0) & \
    ((np.abs(A - B[sorted_idx-1]) < np.abs(A - B[sorted_idx])) )
    return B[sorted_idx-mask]

assert np.array_equal(tho(vec, vals), jpp(vec, vals))
assert np.array_equal(tho(vec, vals), diva(vec, vals))

%timeit tho(vec, vals)   # 366 ms per loop
%timeit jpp(vec, vals)   # 295 ms per loop
%timeit diva(vec, vals)  # 334 ms per loop
```

#### Related Q&A

1. [Find nearest indices for one array against all values in another array - Python / NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349561/find-nearest-indices-for-one-array-against-all-values-in-another-array-python)
2. [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

You have to look along the other axis to get the desired values like this:

```
replaced_vals=vals[np.argmin(np.abs(vec[:, np.newaxis] - vals), axis=1)]
```

Output for your problem:

```
array([  10.,   11.,   11.,  100.,  100.])
```

Answer (score 1):

if `vals` is sorted, `x_k` from `vec` must be rounded to `y_i` from `vals` if :

```
                           (y_(i-1)+y_i)/2 <= x_k < (y_i+y_(i+1))/2.
```

so, yet another solution using `np.searchsorted`, but minimizing operations and at least twice faster :

```
def bm(vec, vals):
    half = vals.copy() / 2
    half[:-1] += half[1:]
    half[-1] = np.inf
    ss = np.searchsorted(half,vec)
    return vals[ss]

%timeit bm(vec, vals)  # 84 ms per loop
```

If `vals` is also sorted you can finish the job with `numba` for another gap :

```
from numba import njit
@njit
def bmm(vec,vals):
    half=vals.copy()/2
    half[:-1] += half[1:]
    half[-1]=np.inf
    res=np.empty_like(vec)
    i=0
    for k in range(vec.size):
        while half[i]<vec[k]:
            i+=1
        res[k]=vals[i]
    return res

%timeit bmm(vec, vals)  # 31 ms per loop
```