# What is "backslash" doing in this context?

Tags: python, numpy, backslash

The following code was [constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841654/find-elements-of-array-one-nearest-to-elements-of-array-two/37842324#37842324) to be an efficent method of finding the the closest pairs for two elements in a list:

```
idx = np.searchsorted(xx, yy, side="left").clip(max=xx.size-1)
mask = (idx > 0) &  \
       ( (idx == len(xx)) | (np.fabs(yy - xx[idx-1]) < np.fabs(yy - xx[idx])) )
out = xx[idx-mask]
```

I have a simple question:  What is the backslash doing in this code? 
I've tried googling and trying different codes to figure it out myself without success, for example:

[image]

Here I see that it doesn't seem like the backslash is an operator that acts on numpy arrays.

Comment: Just a line separator.

Comment: As the error message says: "line continuation character" , it indicates that the line doesn't end there but goes on on the following line. As this only makes sense at the end of a line, you are getting the error you're getting

Comment: Thanks everyone. Seeing the answer, I see that I should've been able to figure it out on my own given the error message. I tried to figure out what the backslash meant instead of just googling the error message. In the future I'll make a better attempt to make sense of the error message first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` is the [line continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162/how-can-i-do-a-line-break-line-continuation-in-python).
Non-whitespace characters after this, will trigger a `SyntaxError`, as you have discovered the hard way.