# How to set markers only at tick positions in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I am aware of the `markevery` option that allows to only place a marker at every n-th point. However, I'm using the `MaxNLocator` to define tick positions and would like to display markers at those tick positions only. How can I display markers at tick positions only, either using an option or manually placing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ticks with `ax.get_xticks()`, find the [closest point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array) corresponding to each xtick and then get the index to the x-values.  With the indices it is easy to plot the xtick-values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# a bar plot with errorbars
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')

def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(x, y, '--')

xtick = ax.get_xticks()

idx = [find_nearest(x, tick) for tick in xtick]

ax.plot(x[idx], y[idx], 'ro')

plt.show()
```