# Finding x and y values corresponding to given z value in 3D numpy object

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph, regression

I have a `numpy` object in Python (`np`) with which I am plotting a graph in `pyplot`. 
It is a 3D graph with `x`, `y` and `z` being lists containing the values for which the graph is to be plotted.
[image: <code>pyplot</code> chart I am getting]
Below is my code (from [here](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6)):

```
data = np.c_[x,y,z]

# regular grid covering the domain of the data
mn = np.min(data, axis=0) - 0.009
mx = np.max(data, axis=0) + 0.009

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0]), np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1]))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()
A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:, :2], np.prod(data[:, :2], axis=1), data[:, :2] ** 2]
C, _, _, _ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:, 2])

# evaluate it on a grid
Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX * YY, XX ** 2, YY ** 2], C).reshape(X.shape)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.2)
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], data[:, 2], c='r', s=50)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.axis('equal')
ax.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

So here, I want to get the values of `x` and `y`, where the value of `z` is closest to `-30`. How do I get those values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: If I understand your question correct, this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following (see also [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array))

```
value = 30.
zid = (np.abs(Z-value)).argmin()
xval = np.reshape(X, -1)[zid]
yval = np.reshape(Y, -1)[zid]
print xval, yval, np.reshape(Z, -1)[zid]
```

I've checked it on the example (https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6) you referred in the question and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) `np.where` to get the indices which satisfy the condition `-30-eps < z < -30+eps` for some tolerance, `eps`, and use these to get the value of `x` and `y`, e.g.

```
eps = 10.
ind = np.where((-30+eps > Z.ravel()) & (Z.ravel() > -30-eps))

print("x=",X.ravel()[ind],"y=",Y.ravel()[ind])
```

I'm a bit unsure exactly how to do this in your case as your plot differs from the example values from the link (please make code in question a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). The idea should be fine.