# Xarray: search for values in a DataArray/Set

Tags: python-xarray

this StackOverflow Q/A: [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

shows how to search for a value in a 1D numpy array. What is the xarray equivalent of searching for values close to a target value both within the data searching along the coordinates

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def f1(x, y, z):
    return 2*x+3*y+4*z

def f2(x, y, z):
    return x/2+y/3+z/4

TestArray=xr.Dataset({'f1Res':(['xCoord', 'yCoord', 'zcoord'], f1(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z))),
            'f2Res':(['xCoord', 'yCoord', 'zCoord'], f2(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z)))},
                  coords={'xCoord':x, 'yCoord':y, 'zCood':z})

TestArray
```

So the first search would be to find the locations of the `f1Res` dataset closest to the target value of -41.2

Second would be to search both the result of `f1Res` and `f2Res` simultaneous for the location closest to the target value of 0.1

Third would be to search for the `xCoord` and `yCoord` for the results closest to 3.15, -2.5 and leave `zCoord` open

Answer (score 0):

So this is a hack I figured out; but be warned I have not tested it extensively. And it only has been tested on Dataarray

```

def xarraySearch(Target, TargetVal):
   """
    Args:
        Target: data from xarray 
        TargetVal: target to search for

```
Return:
    location array 
"""

Res=np.abs(Target-TargetVal).argmin()
ResLoc=np.unravel_index(Res, Target.shape)
return ResLoc
```

```
I did some tested; preliminary testing on the http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html