# How to get location of nearest number in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following DataFrame

```
    0
0   5
1   10
2   15
3   20
```

i want get location of value which is near to *n* value. For example: if **n=7** then nearest number is **5** .
And after this return location of **5** i.e [0] [0]

Comment: What if there's more than on number that is equally close? Also, what if exactly the same? Also, what steps have you taken to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, if n=5, or 6.  nearest number must be 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

Comment: thanks, but what about returning location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and [`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 15, 3: 20}})
n = 7

(n - df[0]).abs().idxmin()
```

[out]

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.argmin to get the closest number index:

```
df[1] = 7
df[2] = df[1] - df[0]
df[2] = df[2].abs()
print(np.argmin(df[2]))
```