# Select data by latitude and longitude

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am using a dataset from DWD (Deutscher Wetterdienst) and want to select data by latitude and longitude. The import works so far. So no problem there. Now I want to select data by latitude and longitude. It works when I try to select data with `sel` when I use x and y.

But not with lat and long. I tried all the answer which I could find, like:

```
ds.sel(latitude=50, longitude=14, method='nearest')
```

but I am getting the error

> ValueError: dimensions or multi-index levels ['latitude', 'longitude'] do not exist

That's my code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
​
​
ds = xr.open_dataset(
            'cosmo-d2_germany_rotated-lat-lon_single-level_2019061721_012_ASWDIFD_S.grib2',
            engine='cfgrib',
            backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys': {'stepUnits': 1}}
        )
​
print(ds)
```

Output:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (x: 651, y: 716)
Coordinates:
    time        datetime64[ns] ...
    step        timedelta64[ns] ...
    surface     int32 ...
    latitude    (y, x) float64 ...
    longitude   (y, x) float64 ...
    valid_time  datetime64[ns] ...
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    ASWDIFD_S   (y, x) float32 ...
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            2
    GRIB_centre:             edzw
    GRIB_centreDescription:  Offenbach 
    GRIB_subCentre:          255
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             Offenbach 
    history:                 2019-07-22T13:35:33 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-
```

Comment: I'm unable to repeat this problem with well formatted grib or grib2 files I have on hand.  Can you post a link to the grib2 file you are working with?

Comment: You can download recent files under https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/nwp/cosmo-d2/grib/21/aswdifd_s/

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

In your file `latitude` and `longitude` are not dimensions but rather helper 2D variables containing coordinate data. In xarray parlance they are called [non-dimension coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html#coordinates) and you cannot slice on them. See also [Working with Multidimensional Coordinates](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/multidimensional-coords.html#examples-multidim).

Comment: Thanks for reference. But i cant find any hints there how solve to problem. When I select one dataset by x, y it returns me the corresponding lat and long. Do have to convert the non-dimension coordnates? I think the problem is that i have 2-dimensional lats and longs.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you regrid the data to a regular grid inside python so that you have latitudes and longitudes as 1D vectors, you would have to make a grid and then interpolate the data over that grid.

Also you need to check https://www.ecmwf.int/sites/default/files/elibrary/2018/18727-cfgrib-easy-and-efficient-grib-file-access-xarray.pdf to see the way to access grib files in xarray. If you dont want to use xarray for this purpose pygrib is another option.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test the solution as I don't have the cfgrib engine installed, but could you try to use

```
numpy.find_nearest(lonarray, lonvalue)
```

to find the lon and lat indexes near your point as per this soln:
[Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

And then select the point using the index directly on the x,y coordinates?

http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a function for the files from the DWD:

```
import pygrib   # https://jswhit.github.io/pygrib/docs/
import numpy as np

def get_grib_data_nearest_point(grib_file, inp_lat, inp_lon):
    """
    Gets the correspondent value to a latitude-longitude pair of coordinates in
    a grib file.

    :param grib_file:   path to the grib file in disk
    :param lat:         latitude
    :param lon:         longitude
    :return:            scalar
    """

    # open the grib file, get the coordinates and values
    grbs = pygrib.open(grib_file)
    grb = grbs[1]
    lats, lons = grb.latlons()
    values = grb.values
    grbs.close()

    # check if user coords are valide
    if inp_lat > max(grb.distinctLatitudes): return np.nan
    if inp_lat < min(grb.distinctLatitudes): return np.nan
    if inp_lon > max(grb.distinctLongitudes): return np.nan
    if inp_lon < min(grb.distinctLongitudes): return np.nan

    # find index for  closest lat (x)
    diff_save = 999
    for x in range(0, len(lats)):
        diff = abs(lats[x][0] - inp_lat)
        if diff < diff_save:
            diff_save = diff
        else:
            break

    # find index for closest lon (y)
    diff_save = 999
    for y in range(0, len(lons[x])):
        diff = abs(lons[x][y] - inp_lon)
        if diff < diff_save:
            diff_save = diff
        else:
            break

    # index the array to return the correspondent value
    return values[x][y]
```

Comment: I believe this code is incorrect.  The answer is off by 1.  the return should be  `return values[ x - 1 ][ y - 1 ]`

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, you can re-grid your data (probably given in curvilinear grid i.e., lat and lon in 2D arrays)  to your desired resolution of 1-D array (lat/lon) , after which you can use `.sel` directly on the lat/lon coords to slice the data.

Check out `xESMF`(https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Curvilinear_grid.html).

Easy, fast interpolation and regridding of `Xarray` fields with good examples and documentation.