# Find nearest values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, search

Is there a numpy-thonic way to get the nearest values between two arrays:

Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
b = np.array([1.1, 3.2, 4.9, 7.2])
c = find_nearests(a, b)
```

c would be the size of b with the nearest elements from a:

```
print(c)
([1, 3, 5, 7])
```

This question is a direct reference to the following one that applies for searching one element in a tab: [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

Comment: Broadcasting, argmin

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array

Comment: This works for only one value @the_darkside