# How can I find the nearest value of a pandas element compared with another entire column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table from here: https://deepnote.com/project/vacunacion-en-Espana-vs-covid-19-UhxqL4bdSfGJjeyb1WDM6A/%2Fnotebook.ipynb. That's a jupyter notebook which downloads every day of vaccination data in Spain and morphs them into different evolution tables. The specific table is this:

| Day | admin doses | complete dosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 210104 | 82834 | 0 |
| 210107 | 207323 | 0 |
| 210108 | 277976 | 0 |
| 210111 | 406091 | 0 |
| 210112 | 488041 | 0 |
| 210113 | 581638 | 0 |
| 210114 | 676186 | 0 |
| 210115 | 768950 | 0 |
| 210118 | 897942 | 4630 |
| 210119 | 966097 | 18682 |
| 210120 | 1025937 | 31284 |
| 210121 | 1103301 | 98112 |
| 210122 | 1165825 | 136912 |
| 210125 | 1237593 | 177396 |
| 210126 | 1291216 | 247394 |
| 210127 | 1356461 | 346132 |
| 210128 | 1395618 | 385518 |
| 210129 | 1474189 | 503732 |
| 210201 | 1609261 | 715784 |
| 210202 | 1673054 | 837038 |
| 210203 | 1764778 | 997956 |
| 210204 | 1865342 | 1172244 |
| 210205 | 1988160 | 1365818 |
| 210208 | 2105033 | 1572814 |
| 210209 | 2167241 | 1677564 |
| 210210 | 2233249 | 1779366 |
| 210211 | 2320507 | 1886556 |
| 210212 | 2423045 | 2000970 |
| 210215 | 2561608 | 2140182 |
| 210216 | 2624512 | 2193844 |
| 210217 | 2690457 | 2238360 |
| 210218 | 2782751 | 2289112 |
| 210219 | 2936011 | 2342052 |
| 210222 | 3090351 | 2394122 |
| 210223 | 3165191 | 2416610 |
| 210224 | 3284678 | 2442366 |
| 210225 | 3436158 | 2463564 |
| 210226 | 3605635 | 2487566 |
| 210301 | 3829465 | 2523696 |
| 210302 | 3908734 | 2533400 |
| 210303 | 4059320 | 2574004 |
| 210304 | 4229092 | 2617826 |
| 210305 | 4471577 | 2684970 |
| 210308 | 4712191 | 2766976 |
| 210309 | 4848648 | 2824472 |
| 210310 | 4989505 | 2895676 |
| 210311 | 5172106 | 3006516 |
| 210312 | 5352767 | 3166488 |
| 210315 | 5644895 | 3387348 |
| 210316 | 5742218 | 3457074 |
| 210317 | 5857085 | 3609230 |
| 210318 | 5993363 | 3773626 |
| 210322 | 6321908 | 4221736 |
| 210323 | 6409196 | 4313196 |
| 210324 | 6620093 | 4552466 |

And I would like to know what is the nearest value of each `complete doses` compared with the entire `admin doses`, in order to know how many days were needed for completing a vaccination period. For instance, at 210129 there were 503732 complete doses, and the nearest value is 488041 admin doses at 210112 - thus 17 days passed between the admin of 488041 doses and 503732 doses.

I tried a good number of options, but nothing works either with raw pandas or with pandas and numpy. In Excel it would be

`{=INDEX(A$2:A$56;MATCH(MIN(ABS(B$2:B$56-C7));ABS(B$2:B$56-C7);0))}`

But I haven't been able to translate it into Pandas

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why are we using C7? If I load this into excel, C7 would be `0`. For your example, I assume we will look at C18?

Comment: also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array) for the numpy version of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def find_nearest(series):
    current_idx = series.loc["index"]
    nearest_idx = np.abs(df["admin doses"] - series.loc["complete dosis"]).argmin()
    day_diff = (days_in_dt[current_idx] - days_in_dt[nearest_idx]).days
    return day_diff

# convert Day column to TimeStamps
days_in_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.Day, format="%y%m%d")

# the result
df["complete dosis"].reset_index().apply(find_nearest, axis=1)
```

```
0      0
1      3
2      4
3      7
4      8
5      9
6     10
7     11
8     14
9     15
10    16
11    17
12    18
13    18
14    18
15    16
16    17
17    17
18    18
19    15
20    14
21    13
22     9
23     7
24     7
25     7
26     7
27     7
28     6
29     7
30     7
31     7
32     8
33    10
34    11
35    12
36    13
37    14
38    14
39    15
40    16
41    16
42    16
43    18
44    19
45    19
46    20
47    17
48    18
49    19
50    19
51    17
52    18
53    19
54    19
dtype: int64
```

We `apply` a function that finds out the day difference to the nearest value. The values passed to the function are of the form:

```
index                8
complete dosis    4630
Name: 8, dtype: int64
```

this is so that we can also get their index value and take the difference later. `reset_index` prior to `apply` gives this index information to the series passed.

Comment: Thanks!

now, when I tested it, this error appears:

`TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype`

It is supposed that this error message appears when argmin is used with no numeric values, but this is not the case AFAIK

Where is the problem?

Thanks again in advance

Comment: @JuanLuisChulilla Perhaps try `df[["admin doses", "complete dosis"]] = df[["admin doses", "complete dosis"]].astype(int)` before applying the function to make sure they are integers?

Comment: thanks a lot again!! it works like a charm. Now, what I'm struggle to understand is how `series.loc` points to each single element of "complete dosis". It's obvious that df.column points to an entire column, but after reading pandas documentation I haven't figure out how `series.loc` works in this case.

Comment: @JuanLuisChulilla We use `.apply` on a data frame over the `axis=1`. (`df["complete dosis"]` itself is a series yes, but we `reset_index` on it and it becomes a data frame; you can run it seperately to see its behaviour). `axis=1` means pandas sends *rows* of this data frame one by one to the function `find_nearest`. As stated in the very last part of the answer, function sees a series in that form each time i.e. column names of the data frame becomes the index names. Then `.loc` is used to access the values corresponding to them e.g. `series.loc["index"] is 8 for the last example and so on.

Comment: Thanks again!! Muchas gracias!! Sukran!!

Answer (score 1):

To find such matches you can use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
result = pd.merge_asof(df, df.sort_values('admin doses'), left_on='complete dosis', right_on='admin doses')
```

This will only set you with values, and from there you can move to calculating what you need.