# Search a value between indexes of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a sorted list(it contains more than 1000 cumulative elements). For example:

`list = [1.236, 2.236, 5.1254, 9.125663, 9.9632, 15.1266, 18.254, 19.3315, 23.3265]`

And I have a target number which is let's say `9.5`. I want to find its position in list. So I want to see index `3rd and 4` (it should be between 3 (9.125663) and 4th (9.9632) indexes) as output without using a for loop.

Do you have an idea about it?
Thank you.

Comment: just subtract your value from the list (with numpy) and look for the closest value to zero:  check out [find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3):

There is [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module for this:

```py
import bisect

the_list = [1.236, 2.236, 5.1254, 9.125663, 9.9632, 15.1266, 18.254, 19.3315, 23.3265]
val = 9.5
pos = bisect.bisect(the_list, val)
```

to get

```
>>> pos
4
```

You can then use `(pos-1, pos)` as `(3, 4)` (might need to check edge cases).

(Side note: [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) is synonymous to `bisect.bisect_right` so the returned `pos` will be *right* to the `val` if it is *already* in the list, e.g. if `val` was `5.1254`, `pos` would be 3).

Comment: Learn something everyday.  This is a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

Used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array) for the answer:

```
import numpy as np

def get_indices(array, value):
    array = np.array(array)

    # Subtract all values in array with value and get index of smallest value which would be the closest value
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()

    #if closest value is greater than target value
    if(array[idx] > value):
        #+1 because you want "3rd and 4th" index, and python starts from 0
        print([idx+1, idx+2])

    #if closest value is lesser than target value
    elif(array[idx] < value):
        print([idx, idx+1])
    
    else:
        print([idx+1])

array = [1.236, 2.236, 5.1254, 9.125663, 9.9632, 15.1266, 18.254, 19.3315, 23.3265]
value = 9.5
get_indices(array, 9.5)  ## prints [3,4]
get_indices(array, 10.5) ## prints [4,5]
```