# How to extract specific part of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have the following data lets call it y with the corresponding x values. Plotting `plt.plot(x,y)` results in: [image] I now want to extract a specific part of that data that is between the x-values of 8.6075 and 8.62. Plotting the part using `plt.xlim(8.6075, 8.62)`[image] gives the following. I have tried to find the indices using of the x-values using `index1=np.where(x==8.6075), index2=np.where(x==8.62)` and than just cutting out that specific part of the data using `y_cutout = y[index1:index2]`. The problem was that the exact values 8.6075 and 9.62 have no indices that they are defined on.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array you can modify the codes there, return the index instead of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the index of the nearest value by creating a new array of the differences between the values in the original array and the target, then find the index of the minimum value in the new array.

For example, starting with an array of random values in the range 5.0 - 10.0:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(low=5.0, high=10.0, size=(20,))
print(x)
```

Find the index of the value closest to 8 using:

```
target = 8

diff_array = np.absolute(x - target)
print(diff_array)

index = diff_array.argmin()
print(index, x[index])
```

Output:

```
[7.74605146 8.31130556 7.39744138 7.98543982 7.63140243 8.0526093
 7.36218916 6.62080638 6.18071939 6.54172198 5.76584536 8.69961399
 5.83097522 9.93261906 8.21888006 7.63466418 6.9092988  9.2193369
 5.41356164 5.93828971]

[0.25394854 0.31130556 0.60255862 0.01456018 0.36859757 0.0526093
 0.63781084 1.37919362 1.81928061 1.45827802 2.23415464 0.69961399
 2.16902478 1.93261906 0.21888006 0.36533582 1.0907012  1.2193369
 2.58643836 2.06171029]

3 7.985439815743841
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a selection by following

```
y_cutout = y[(x >= 8.6075) & (x <= 8.62)]
```

(Fixed as @AcaNg mentioned in the comment)

Comment: Did you mean `y_cutout = y[(x >= 8.6075) & (x <= 8.62)]` ?

Comment: @AcaNg, You are right. y's in the brackets should have been x. Let me fix it.