# Find closest elements of two lists - the best way

Tags: python, numpy

I have two lists(or columns of dataframe - doesn't matter) of numerical values:

```
L1 = [1, 0.5, 3, 7, 4.7]
L2 = [2, 0.4, 8, 0.3, 5]
```

for example. I need to correlate these lists and find pairs`(indexOfElementFromL1, indexOfElementFromL2)` which corresponds min diff of two elements. For example, for my example it should be:
`(0,1), (1,1), (2,0), (3,2), (4,4).` Really what I want - find closest element L2 to each one of L1. Of course I could naive approch like:

```
for el1 in L1:
  for el2 in L2:
    ....
```

But I'd to like to see more correct solution

Answer (score 5):

You can do it really fast by converting your lists to numpy arrays and using numpy broadcasting:

```
a1 = np.array(L1)
a2 = np.array(L2)

indexes = abs(a1[:, None] - a2).argmin(axis=1)
out = list(enumerate(indexes))
```

Output:

```
>>> indexes
array([1, 1, 0, 2, 4])

>>> out
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: I think there is no good answer to this question because lists are not sorted. But for all +1

Comment: @Corralien I disagree - this is, in fact, the best solution. The arrays don't need to be sorted for this to work - it uses numpy broadcasting and the wonderful `argmin` (synonymous with `idxmin` in Pandas) to efficiently compute what the OP wants.

Comment: Do you think numpy (fortran, C) doesn't iterate over the two lists? Maybe all of you have the fastest solution for a CPU but you have the same algorithm. Loop over 2 lists...

Comment: Admittedly I'm not sure about numpy internals, but I don't believe it's looping over the lists (I think that's the idea behind broadcasting). It's the same algorithm as the others' solution but more vectorized (as much as possible).

Comment: I wrote that because the OP said he *could use naive approach* but the question is what is a good approach.

Comment: Broadcasting is just a view of your numpy array in memory. How can you guess the closest value of first item of L1 is not the last item of L2 without iterate over all elements of L2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241881/discussion-between-richardec-and-corralien).

Answer (score 2):

taken from another answer; though I do not know how to flag for such:

[Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np

L1 = [1, 0.5, 3, 7, 4.7]
L2 = [2, 0.4, 8, 0.3, 5]

def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

for el1 in L1:
     print(find_nearest(L2, el1))
```

Comment: It doesn't print the indices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how an answer could be 'more correct', but this is how I'd do it. I like it more than a cramped one liner because it's still readable.

```
L1 = [1, 0.5, 3, 7, 4.7]
L2 = [2, 0.4, 8, 0.3, 5]


def find_closest(x):
    l2_diffs = [abs(x - y) for y in L2]
    return l2_diffs.index(min(l2_diffs))


res = [(i, find_closest(x)) for i, x in enumerate(L1)]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use brute force methods using for loops or taking advantage of broadcasting, as you can see in other answers.

The problem comes when the lists are large. If that's the case, for loops will  be slow and broadcasting will take a lot of memory.

The alternative is to use a search algorithm like [FLANN](https://pypi.org/project/wbia-pyflann/):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pyflann import FLANN

>>> L1 = np.array([[1, 0.5, 3, 7, 4.7]]).T      # Data points as rows
>>> L2 = np.array([[2, 0.4, 8, 0.3, 5]]).T

>>> idx, _ = FLANN().nn(pts=L2, qpts=L1)
>>> idx
array([1, 1, 0, 2, 4], dtype=int32)

>>> list(enumerate(idx))
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Or, if you want to perform multiple queries:

```
>>> flann = FLANN()
>>> flann.build_index(pts=L2)           # Build search index
>>> idx, _ = flann.nn_index(qpts=L1)    # Query
```