# Compare a column against a dictionary in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a dictionary:

```
dict = {10: 1, 50: 2, 200: 3, 500: 4}
```

And a Dask DataFrame:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1| 24|
|  1| 49|
|  2|125|
|  3|400|
+---+---+
```

I want to groupBy a and get the minimum b value. After that, I want to check which dict key is closest to b and create a new column with the dict value.

As a example, when b=24, the closest key is 10. So I want to assign the value 1.
This is the result I am expecting:

```
+---+---+-------+
|  a|  b|closest|
+---+---+-------+
|  1| 24|      1|
|  1| 49|      2|
|  2|125|      3|
|  3|400|      4|
+---+---+-------+
```

I have found something similar with PySpark. I have not been able to make it run, but it apparently run for other people. Sharing it anyway for reference.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 24),
        (1, 49),
        (2, 125),
        (3, 400)
    ],
    ["a", "b"]
)

dict = {10:1, 50:2, 200: 3, 500: 4}

def func(value, dict):
    closest_key = (
        value if value in dict else builtins.min(
            dict.keys(), key=lambda k: builtins.abs(k - value)
        )
    )
    score = dict.get(closest_key)
    return score

df = (
    df.groupby('a')
        .agg(
            min('b')
        )
    ).withColumn('closest', func('b', dict))
```

From what I understand, I think on the spark version the calculation was done per row and I have not been able to replicate that.

Comment: I dont wanna be that guy friendo, but i am gonna be that guy. Why use a dict and the idea of closest, if what you are doing is basically a conjunction of if statements, but with more ifs. Functions like np.where or pandas mask would be very appliable and more easily understandable. If you want i can show you how

Comment: Sure, I am open to try a different solution.
This was the solution proposed as the function to calculate the closest one will be used to create a few different columns, each one with its own dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using pure dask in case you don't want to rely on other packages.

Sample to test:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

_dict = {10: 1, 50: 2, 200: 3, 500: 4}
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,2,3], "b":[24,49,125,400]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

Function:

```
def get_closest(value: int, boundaries: dict) -> int:
    keys = np.array(list(boundaries.keys()))
    closest = keys[np.abs(keys - value).argmin()]
    score = boundaries[closest]

    return score
```

Then we apply it:

```
ddf['closest'] = ddf['b'].apply(
    get_closest,
    args=(_dict, True),
    meta=('int32')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of a row-rise operation, you can think of it as a partition-wise operation. If my interpretation is off, you can still use this sample I wrote for the most part with a few tweaks.

I will show a solution with [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue) that lets you just define your logic in Pandas, and then bring it to Dask. This will return a Dask DataFrame.

First some setup, note that `df` is a Pandas DataFrame. This is meant to represent a smaller sample you can test on:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np

_dict = {10: 1, 50: 2, 200: 3, 500: 4}
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,2,3], "b":[24,49,125,400]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
```

and then we define the logic. This is written to handle one partition so everything in column `a` will already be the same value.

```
def logic(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # handles the logic for 1 group. all values in a are the same
    min_b = df['b'].min()
    keys = np.array(list(_dict.keys()))
    # closest taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465997/11163214
    closest = keys[np.abs(keys - min_b).argmin()]
    closest_val = _dict[closest]
    df = df.assign(closest=closest_val)
    return df
```

We can test this on Pandas:

```py
logic(df.loc[df['a'] == 1])
```

and we'll get:

```
    a   b   closest
0   1   24  1
1   1   49  1
```

So then we can just bring it to Dask with Fugue. We just need to call the `transform` function:

```
from fugue import transform

ddf = transform(ddf,
          logic,
          schema="*,closest:int",
          partition={"by":"a"},
          engine="dask")
ddf.compute()
```

This can take in either Pandas or Dask DataFrames and will output the Dask DataFrame because we specified the `"dask"` engine. There is also a `"spark"` engine if you want a Spark DataFrame.

Schema is a requirement for distributed computing so we specify the output schema here. We also partition by column a.

Comment: The last line, `ddf.compute` makes it a pandas dataframe. Avoid it if you want a dask dataframe. Other than that, this worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

So here it is another approach for you friend, this will return a numpy array, but hey it will be faster than spark, and you can easily reindex it.

```
import numpy as np
a = pydf.toNumpy()
a = a[:,1] # Grabs your b column
np.where([a <=10,a <=50,a<=200,a<=500],[1,2,3,4],a) # Check the closest values and fill them with what you want
```