# Can I use multiprocessing from an external library to speed up a function matching two lists?

Tags: python, performance, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that is taking up ~95% of my execution time, I use it multiple times and it's making my program incredibly slow. I cant use the built in multiprocessing library because of my reliance on Pycharm:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53235.

Here's my core problem:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import ray # confirmed this library works in my env 

def get_matched_time(match: np.ndarray, template: np.ndarray) -> list:
    """
    Return an array containing the closest value 
    in the template array to the input array.
    Args: 
        match : for each value of match, 
                find the closest value in template.
        template : values to match to

    Returns: 
        matched_time : iterable of size match.size containing 
                       values found  in template closest to each value in match.
    """

    matched_time, matched_index = [], []

    for t in match: # for each and every match value
        temp = [abs(t - valor) for valor in template] # iterate template value for closest time
        matched_index.append(temp.index(min(temp))) #add the index
    return [(template[idx]) for idx in matched_index]

(...)
```

The `match` array (or any iterable) can vary between 10 and 12,000 values. The template array is usually upwards of 10,000 values as well, but always larger than match.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    returned_time = get_matched_time
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Execution time: {end - start} s")

>>>Execution time: 12.573657751083374 s
```

Just in-case its unclear:

```
match = [1.1, 2.1, 5.1] # will always be smaller than template
template = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

My desired output is `[1.0, 2.0, 5.0]` in any iterable form, order doesn't really matter because I can just sort by value afterwords.

I'm hoping to be able to assign each loop of `for t in match` to a process. I have been trying this with ray [Ray Parallel Iterators](https://docs.ray.io/en/releases-0.8.4/iter.html) but I don't understand the documentation to implement. If anybody can recommend a more efficient method, or a way to incorporate multiprocessing via `ray` or another library, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: the PyCharm issue you have linked only seems to occur in the Python Console for me, not when you run that same code as a file

Comment: The console is really all I use, I don't want to switch to running code as files for the rest of the development of this project

Comment: why are you using the console? when developing any project that's more than 10 lines (or less) you use files and then run those files (console is meant just for quick prototyping or sth), PyCharm makes it pretty easy to run them too, you can even add a keyboard shortcut to it

Comment: In my run configuration, I just have the checkbox Run with Python Console checked, primarily so I can sort threw variables and its just the way I've always done it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can significantly improve the performance of your search by using vectorized numpy calls in place of your iterations. In particular, we can replace this code:

```
for t in match: # for each and every match value
        temp = [abs(t - valor) for valor in template] 
        matched_index.append(temp.index(min(temp)))
```

With abundantly faster numpy operations. Rather than searching, we use vectorized maths to find all the absolute differences between `match` and `template`. Then we find the minima of these absolute values and the argument value of the minima. Finally, return the matches:

```
def get_matched_time(match: np.ndarray, template: np.ndarray) -> np.array:
    match = match.reshape(-1, 1)
    a = np.abs(match - template)
    mins = np.argmin(a, axis=1)
    return np.array([template[mins[i]] for i in range(len(match))])
```

In this code, I return an array since the inputs are arrays and this make the code interoperable with numpy functions that might be used on the ouputs.

Comment: Yeah this definitely did the trick. Fleshed out example of what @MarcusMuller was saying. This approach reduced the execution time from 12.7 s to 0.3 seconds. Thank you :)

Comment: Please accept my answer, since you found it helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more parallelism, you need better code.

So, you're using numpy, but still use a Python loop to go through all elements in the array. To make matters worse, you're not even just doing that with a for-loop generator expression, you're actually making a temporary list by encasing it in `[]`!

That's a big bad idea. You can express the same idea, calculate the distance to my single value, simply as subtraction and absolute value, on the whole input array. That will very likely lead to such a speedup that you could live with your result.

Then you first find the minimum element, then again go searching for the minimum element, instead of just asking numpy to give you the argmin. What a colossal replication of effort! [There's better and easier ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566508/4433386).

However, honestly, you're going to a sortable array to find an element, but instead of being any smart about that, you just check all elements, whether or not you could be much smarter about "narrowing down" on the closest value. You're using an exhausting search where a guided walking to the right point would work; don't.

Take your template array, sort it once (not every time you use this function, once), then use e.g. a binary search to find the closest element. That's logarithmic in effort, not multiple times linear like your current code.

If your problem was large numerically (12000 values is not large for a modern computer in a way that would justify making indirect memory accesses), you'd need to think about data structures that represent searchable vector spaces (your vector space is 1D, so that makes the binary search with a heap the equivalent), like k-d trees.

All in all your code reads like you are not realizing numpy has documentation that you can use to find methods like argmin.

Comment: (Seriously, finding 10000 closest values in the same can 10000 element vector should not take 12 seconds. It's an operation that greatly benefits from l2 caches, so you actually benefit from *not* perfectly parallelizing this.)

Comment: I see your point, and appreciate the response. I agree and knew this wasn't the most efficient manner to do this, and will look into some more efficient methods.

Comment: You will really like the answer I linked to in the middle. It just gives a way to get the index of the closest element much quicker than your current approach.